# Publicly Teaching Halacha

Tags: halacha, gentiles, adult-learning

I was looking at [the Daily Halachah Yahoo group](http://groups.yahoo.com/group/DailyHalachah/) and was a little bit surprised at this statement:

> It is therefore forbidden for Jews to teach non-Jews Halachah

Is this true?

(See a [related question](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/42/publicly-teaching-halachah) on the Meta).

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1583/teaching-written-torah-to-christians

Comment: Rabbi Frazer's lecture on this topic: http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/720819/Rabbi_Ezra_Frazer/Teaching_Torah_to_Non-Jews

Comment: See [this excellent essay](http://torahmusings.com/2011/01/is-yutorah-mutar/) for more, especially with regards to posting free material online.

Comment: Very similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33964

Answer (score 10):

Even if it is true, it wouldn't be a concern on this site, because the [primary] purpose is for other Jews to see it. Even if we're answering to a non-Jewish user (which of course, is impossible to tell) there are still other Jews who will see it and benefit from it.

To give it a real world analogy:

Publishing a sefer would have the same problem. Any non-jew can pick up a sefer and read it...

And for an actual source: Rabbi Mechanic tells the story of how he once had to speak at a class about religion, where only one of the class attendees was Jewish. His stipulation for coming to speak was that the one Jew in the class show up that day. One of the reasons he gave for that stipulation, was to get around the problem of teaching non-Jews Torah.

Comment: To me, this answer seems more suited for the meta-discussion question than this question.

Comment: @Peter Of The Corn You are correct. But Isaac over there said to put all answers here. So what to do?

Comment: Did he? I don't remember seeing that...

Comment: @PeterOfTheCorn Maybe I misunderstood (read too quick) but Issac commented over there "I recommend that you leave this one as-is except for adding a link to the other." I took that to mean, put all answers on main and just have link in meta...

Comment: I was thinking of that same exact story of Rav Mechenic when I wrote my answer. I think I heard it here- http://www.torahanytime.com/scripts/media.php?file=media/Rabbi/Daniel_Mechanic/2009-02-09/The_Truth_of_Judaism_My_Conversation_With_Hollywood/Rabbi__Daniel_Mechanic__The_Truth_of_Judaism_My_Conversation_With_Hollywood__2009-02-09.wmv

Comment: The SITE might have one purpose, but ANSWERING THE OP who is non-Jewish is an issue INDEPENDENT of the status of the site.

Answer (score 7):

HaRav Yitzhak Yosef Shelit"a holds (Yalkut Yosef 246) that as long as there are Jews mixed in the group of teaching, it is permitted.