# Is it forbidden to teach Torah to non-Jews on Mi Yodeya?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, torah-study, stackexchange

I have noticed that many Christians and Messianics post questions on Mi Yodeya and I'm wondering if the prohibition of teaching the Torah to non-Jews would apply in a forum like this or if it only intends to prohibit personal interaction, etc. which is not a concern online (necessarily).

Comment: perhaps this belongs on meta.

Comment: You're teaching anyone who comes to this website. You can ask the same question about people writing seforim (especially in non-Jewish languages, such as the Rambam)

Comment: Highly related (duplicate?): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7260 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33964. Meta: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/42 and http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1436.

Comment: Duplicate with useful answers: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23042 Non-Jews learning and being taught Torah.