# Is posting Torah to the internet considered teaching gentiles Torah?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, torah-study, chinuch-education

Does the prohibition of teaching Torah to gentiles encompass putting Torah out on the internet for all to see?

Comment: Just edited the question. How do I take away the duplicate?

Comment: It has now been reopened after 4 higher-scoring members voted to do so

Comment: It depends who the intended audience of the *divrei torah* is, otherwise it would be *assur* for Artscroll to print translation gemaras on the basis these are bought by clergy.

Comment: Some answers here may help: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7260/128

Comment: The prohibition is on eved kochavim u'mazalot to osek in Torah; lammud is not forbidden.