# Is there a translation of the words of Ben Sira?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, english, translation, apocrypha

Is there an authoritative translation into English of the works of Ben Sira (his wisdom, his alphabet)?

Comment: Are you looking for the traditional Latin/English/Christian version, or one that is translated from the recently rediscovered Hebrew?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a version online [here](http://www.biblestudytools.com/kjva/ben-sira/1.html). It seems that they have a few different translations from the drop-down menu (the one on display is KJV).

Comment: If one's looking for Christian translations, he should note that it's also called "Ecclesiasticus".

Comment: @msh210 Are you saying I shouldn't have given a Christian translation because if the questioner wanted it he would have asked for "Ecclesiasticus"? "Ben Sira" seems to also be the non-Jewish way of referring to it (though I guess the questioner could ([?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9869/is-a-jew-allowed-to-participate-on-christianity-se)) have asked on Christianity.SE)

Comment: I did not mean that, no. I was merely providing a (I hope) helpful pointer for seekers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Aaronson Press has a book containing the entire Apocrypha in English.