# Attending a Super Bowl party where alcohol and Kosher food is provided

Tags: halacha, liquor-beer, sport-athletics, performance-entertainment

May I attend a Super Bowl party run by their office or school? Assume there will be all types of alcohols available, and Kosher food.

Also, if I'm allowed, what are the ground laws while attending this party? Are there any special regulations during the party, e.g. alcohol-related ground laws?

(**Of course [CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi).**)

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that there are halachic issues? Any reason to think that they pertain to Super Bowl parties particularly?

Comment: I recommend the ideas of Hukot HaGoyim, Moshav Letzim, and Bitul Torah.

Comment: The halacha according to the Shulchan Aruch is that one may not drink beer in a place of non-Jews (such as in their houses or stores) since doing so may bring to chasnus Y.D. 114:1

Comment: and what if it was done illegally? http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/recycled/2010/02/is_my_super_bowl_party_illegal.html

Comment: wow that is rally strange I think alot of ppl ignore the law

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8794.

Comment: @simchashatorah, if your knowledge of the _SA_ is what prompted the question, please edit it into the question.

Comment: It is not and not the main point I would say more What gabriel says is my motivation

Comment: @simchastorah: the Ramo is lenient for beer and hard liquor (based on a number of Rishonim, including the Meiri) and thus most people are lenient about drinking in non-Jewish establishments.

Comment: most people are lenient about drinking in non-Jewish establishments I know this what is it based on is my interest?

Comment: @Menachem we usually say dina demalchuta only bedine mamonot.

Comment: @HachamGabriel: copyright infringement is dinei mamanot

Comment: @Menachem I didn't even read the article because I presumed it was speaking of under-aged drinking. Mehila.

Comment: @Curiouser Most beer is made of barley, not wheat.

Comment: Very relevant article in light of a nasty op-ed piece in a recent issue of Mishpacha.  See my answer.

Answer (score 9):

May a Jew watch sports at all?

It's a fine line.

[See this article](http://www.dinonline.org/2012/01/29/what-to-do-for-recreation/), which talks about the fine line between recreation / relaxation time (permitted) and wasting time (forbidden).  It specifically mentions watching the Super Bowl.

May a Jew drink alcohol with non-Jews?

> The  halacha according to the  Shulchan Aruch is that one may not drink beer in a 
>   place of non-Jews (such as in their houses or stores) since doing so may bring to chasnus
>   (intermarriage).  However, this is only if one is drinking for a long time, but if he makes it quick and is not accustomed to do doing it, then it is permitted.  A place of goyim means a bar where they consume these drinks, but a store which is not meant to sit down is not included in this halacha.
>   **The Rema says that the custom is to permit beer made from honey or grain.**

(excerpted from [here](http://www.thehalacha.com/attach/Volume4/Issue20.pdf) )

So, if you think that you need a Superbowl Party's worth of time for recreation, you can go watch the game.  If you hold by the Rema, you can even have a beer or two.

Comment: When the Rama says "grain" he's pretty clearly referring to *wheat* not *barley*.

Comment: @DoubleAA: so does the Rema hold that one can even drink a beer made of barley?

Comment: @unforgettableid Rema himself probably thought that was permitted. But what he wrote in Shulchan Arukh sounds IMHO like it is forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, football is a very distant descendant of the Roman gladitorial games in terms of its popularity and regard by the public, especially since injuries are quite common and occasionally even inflicted upon a player for strategic reasons.  If I remember correctly, a Jew may not be a spectator at any blood sport, either at the Collisseum (then) or the Super Bowl (modern equivalent).  You therefore shouldn't attend, if only because your "choseness", that is, "separateness" from the rest of the world, would be under threat :)

Answer (score 0):

An op-ed piece by a contributor to Mishpacha magazine (January ?? 2016 -- not yet online) condemned Jewish attendance at Superbowl parties and compared this cultural "infiltration" into Orthodox Jewish homes as something akin to terrorism.  Frankly, I don't think he's right.  While watching sports, or attending parties around sports, may involve issues of bitul Torah and secularization, and the commercials may be, at times, too racy to expose our children to, I have to note, that I've known many roshei yeshivos and respected Orthodox rabbis who enjoyed sports on television, including the Superbowl, although I can't say I know any who attended a superbowl party, per se.  Some examples:  The mashgiach ruchani of RSA, HaRav Shmuel Niman was, before his current illness, a huge sports fan as are his sons.  I heard him speak to my congregation and hinted to any Redskins season ticket holders, that he would not turn down an invitation to go to a game.  Rabbi Gedaliah Anemer, zt'l, the rounding Rosh HaYeshiva of the Yeshiva of Greater Washington, praised my organization of a synagogue event that drew more than 90 members to a AA baseball game, although he turned down my invitation for him to join us and throw out the first pitch (a privilege we would have earned if we drew 100 attendees).  Also, he once sermonized how he once almost blew off attending mincha with a minyan because he was watching an exciting Redskins game on TV (he said, "you know it was a long time ago because they were good then").  He was also known to have corrected a yeshiva student's description of the infield fly rule.  The OU in 2014 co-sponsored a [kosher Superbowl party](https://www.ou.org/news/superbowl_kosher_halftime_show_nachum_segal_network/), adding kosher entertainment provided by the Nachum Segal Network.  Moreover, in Teaneck, NJ, there is a sports bar/restaurant called the Dog House, under the rabbinic supervision of Rabbi Zushe Yosef Blech, Hasgachat Kashrus of Kehillas Bais Ben Zion, Monsey, NY, one of the leading experts in kashrus in the US.  In the US, attendance at sporting events has been important in the bonding of Orthodox Jewish fathers and sons (daughters, too), and has been a terrific site for a shiddach date for couples (my daughter and son-in-law had their first date at a Nationals game).

Rabbi Emanuel Feldman, a Mishpacha Magazine columnist and the rabbi emeritus of Congregation Beth Jacob in Atlanta, not to mention the brother of HaRav Aharon Feldman, shlita, Rosh HaYeshiva of Ner Israel, wrote how he attended a Braves World Series game, feeling somewhat guilty that he might be recognized as someone who has better things to do with his time than to surrender to his boy-hood passion for baseball.  In an article for [Torah from Dixie](http://www.tfdixie.com/special/feldman1.htm) he retells the story as an entertaining morality tale, also describing the pros and cons of his attendance.  At one point in the game, he athletically caught a foul ball which was seen by millions on television, and was the talk of Orthodox Jews around the world, even among those who do not watch television.  His catch was cheered by his Atlanta congregants and others in the US.  But at his Israeli home in the charedi Har Nof section of Israel, the reaction made him nervous and glad that his children were all married off.

The answer to you is, "it depends" on your hashgafa and your standing in your community.  By all means consult your local rabbi or rebbe for guidance.

Comment: You fail to mention that the "Dog House" in Teaneck is under supervision from Monsey because the local rabbinate deemed it too inappropriate for supervision. Makes me wonder how else you've skewed the data.

Comment: @doubleaa I'm not from Teaneck, how would I know that?  Rabbi Feldman's article seems to assert that sports are ok for some but not others.  When a rebbe takes his campers to a ballgame is that inappropriate?

Comment: @DoubleAA have you ever met Rabbi Blech? Do you know his reputation?

Comment: I have not met him, but I'm sure his food is very Kosher. That's not really the point, though.

Comment: It's true that the OU co-sponsored the Super Bowl party. But maybe their goal wasn't to get more Jews to watch the Super Bowl. Maybe their real goal was in order to help keep less-observant Jews away from non-kosher Super Bowl parties.