# Halachic law about inviting a Jew for dinner by a Gentile

Tags: halacha, food, gentiles, kashrut-kosher, hachnasat-orchim-guests

I know that Observant Jews are commanded by law to eat Kashrut or kosher, so can I as a Gentile invite my Jewish friend for dinner, for example at a marriage or engagement party? What food items should I offer him to eat? I know most of the things on our table may not be considered kosher as per halachik law, so my question is which food items I can offer him for eating, or is it better just not to invite at all?

Comment: [Similar.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8794)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many degrees and styles of kashrut observance.

Some people will be fine just by not mixing meat and dairy and excluding non-kosher animals. Others will politely refuse to eat anywhere that is not 100% kosher (which again, is a definition that might vary even among the most orthodox)

The best way to be sure is to ask your friend what his needs are. He will surely appreciate it.

Answer (score 6):

You are certainly welcome to invite him. He can chose whether or not to come. If the food is being prepared in a non-kosher facility, really the only things that he would be able to eat without special effort are unprepared foods like raw fruits and vegetables. There are ways to make kosher food in unkosher ovens; however, that could take considerable extra effort (double wrapping everything, securing kosher food, etc.). I would recommend speaking with him personally to determine what his needs are.

Comment: your answer is guiding me, definitely I want to offer him kosher food only, How if I purchase ready kosher cooked food from kosher restaurant and offer him, Can I need to serve that kosher food in new plates, as our plates may be in contact with non kosher foods in the past.

Comment: @Ishrat Yes, if you order food from a kosher restaurant, you could serve that to him, and yes it should be on new plates. Also, be aware that you should not heat it up in the oven without proper guidance from a rabbi. That could potentially make the food non-kosher unless it is done properly.

Comment: @Ishrat, a kosher vender (caterer, restaurant, or deli with a hot-foods section) can give you food and instructions for preparing it without damaging its kashrut.  I've been to non-kosher gatherings (e.g. at conferences) where the organizers were able to arrange for this for me.  Alternatively, for say a wedding I really wanted to be at, I could just go and not eat.

Comment: @Ishrat - Most Kosher caterers in NYC simply offer recyclable (paper/plastic) plates, cups and utensils with the food. Not sure about other places.

Comment: If the vegetables are a type which is known to have bugs in it, then you should remove them to the best of your ability. Here are a few links about how to thoroughly check vegetables http://star-k.org/bugcheckingquickreference.pdf and   http://www.crcweb.org/fruit%20&%20veg%20guide.php