# How to suggest a kosher restaurant for a meeting?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, how-to, business, social-convention

A colleague suggested a restaurant for a meeting which is not glatt kosher or non kosher. What is a good way to recommend a different restaurant which is glatt kosher without offending him?

Would a different response be appropriate for an Observant,  non-Observant or non-Jewish colleague?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8794

Comment: This seems off topic. as not about Judaism.

Comment: This seems primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In most cases, when this sort of thing comes up I say something like: "I have some dietary restrictions and wouldn't be able to eat there; could we meet at $other_restaurant instead?".

For someone known to be observant, I would instead say something like: "last I heard they aren't kosher; has that changed?"  That is, presume that the other person has the same problem you do.  So either he'll say "no, they're under supervision now" (great!) or he'll explain how he's planning to solve the problem ("yeah, I know, but they have a fruit salad that works").

What to do if the person is a non-observant Jew is more complicated.  Unless it's someone you're close to, anything that sounds like rebuke over his non-observance is likely to cause resentment.  I've found that *modeling better behavior* without pushing works better, so I personally would use approximately the same approach as for gentiles, making it about *my* needs and leaving unsaid that perhaps he ought to be considering that too.

Finally, I've been assuming in this answer that this is a meeting between the two of you.  If, instead, it's a larger group for business purposes (your sales team is taking the customer out to a swanky steak house, for example), you might be better off going and drinking a Coke than trying to influence the decision.  You have to judge such situations on a case-by-case basis.  (For additional thoughts on workplace meals, see [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8794/472) (h/t msh210).)

Comment: I think this question might be asking about a restaurant which is kosher but not glatt (i.e. it's a hechsher the asker doesn't accept). Especially because the OP asks about responding to an observant colleague.

Comment: @Daniel oh, I didn't pick up on "kosher but not glatt" as the issue, though the question also says "or non-kosher".

Comment: Re "you might be better off going and drinking a Coke" see also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44690 / http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/208

Comment: @msh210 I've several times heard the suggestion to have a cold drink (water, Coke, etc) without food if you must attend, though I don't have a source for it.  But yes, people should consider possible *marit ayin* when making the decision to go.

Comment: The last paragraph is very good.  This is a right behavior to deal alone with the halachic issues

Comment: I think OU or CRC has an article that addresses "marit ayin" concerns when attending business meetings at non-kosher restaurants. I'll see if  I can locate it, but, you might find it before me. Offhand, I think it stated that there are circumstances where attending such a meal meeting would be allowed.

Comment: Congratulations and *Yeyasher Kocheich* on co-winning the [Best Answer Contest for the first quarter of 5777](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4231/best-answer-contest-winners-first-quarter-of-5777)!