# How does Judaism regard the different denominations of Christianity vis-a-vis Avoda Zara?

Tags: avodah-zarah, christianity

There's been lots of talk about whether Christianity is Avodah Zara.

Are there any distinctions between denominations, say which ones have more statues?

Comment: i think this would be the rough order from less to more of an issue: unitarianism, liberal protestantism, protestantism, catholicism, eastern orthodox

Comment: IMO duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89. It asks whether Christianity is _avoda zara_. If the answer is different for different denominations, answers there should say so.

Comment: @ArielK why do you rank eastern orthodox lower than catholic?

Comment: I think they are bigger believers in icon veneration and maybe also in praying to saints.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27969/is-unitarianism-considered-to-be-idolatry?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

A building could become prohibited from benefit if it was constructed to house an "idol." Thus it was ruled a century ago that a Methodist church, which does not house any "idols", could be bought by Jews and converted to a synagogue (or any other use for that matter). This isn't a question of theology, it's one of whether there's a physical object in the building that looks like an "idol." Whereas a Catholic Church or further still, an Eastern Orthodox one ... could get a lot trickier.

Similarly, all sorts of questions were asked during WWII about saving one's life by claiming to be a Christian. One responsa discussed the potential difference between wearing a cross (just a t-shape) and a crucifix (which has someone on it).

As ArielK noted, Unitarians pose the least issues. As such Rabbi Yehuda Herzl Henkin permits one to enter a Unitarian church.

Comment: Where is the Tshuva regarding converting churches to shuls (or entering churches)?

Comment: _Thus it was ruled a century ago_ ruled by whom?