# Is Unitarianism considered to be idolatry?

Tags: avodah-zarah, christianity

Many Jewish authorities consider Christianity to be idolatry due to their belief in a "Holy Trinity." Is that position universal for all Christians, or is it specific only to particular individuals or denominations that actually believe in the trinity?

In particular, is [Unitarianism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarianism) widely considered to be idolatry among rabbinic authorities?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12235.

Comment: @msh210, possibly, but this question wasn't fully answered there; it was only mentioned in passing.

Comment: Daniel, if it wasn't fully answered there and you wish more attention to be paid to it there, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty. Closing (see also http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=9008826#9008826 et seq.).

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, no it's not "idolatry."

(Like Islam, it does not accept our Written and Oral Law as binding on Jews and thus it would be "heresy" for a Jew to follow, but not idolatry per se.)

Rabbi Yehuda Herzl Henkin therefore allows one to enter a Unitarian church, and similarly Rabbi Hershel Schachter allows a Unitarian church to be converted into a synagogue. (Whereas if a building had been constructed to house and protect an "idol", there would be serious problems for Jews to use that building for any purpose.)

Comment: Do you have citations for your claims that R' Henkin allows one to enter a Unitarian church and that R' Schachter allows the church to be converted into a synagogue?

Comment: RHS - a recent Hilchos Beis Haknesses shiur on yutorah.

Comment: RYHH - pretty sure it's in Bnei Banim; heard it on a Rabbi Linzer shiur on Christianity vis-a-vis Judaism.