# Is Sabellianism avodah zarah (idolatry)?

Tags: theology, avodah-zarah, christianity

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabellianism

They do not believe that God is three in one. They believes that God, being omnipotent, can appear to humans in many forms, including becoming human like Jesus.

Is that avodah zarah too?

On another edge, Christianity also have [Unitarianism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarianism) which I think have the same concept of God with judaism. In this question, I am asking for Sabellianism, which is somewhere between Unitarianism and trinity "flavor" of Christianity.

Comment: Extremely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12235/3

Answer (score 3):

The Rambam states that believing G-d has a body makes one a Min (a heretic), all the more so saying G-d was incarnated.

As for Unitarianism, it would probably be like Islam, which believes in false prophets rather than being outright Avoda Zara.

Of course, in either case, it would be forbidden for a Jew to adopt Unitarianism or Islam; but would not have to die rather than do so like outright Avoda Zara. (i.e. under duress, it would be permitted, according to the Rambam, though not all authorities agree with this since a few say Islam is also Avodah Zara, to say "I am a Muslim" in order to save one's life, but not so in the case of believing in the incarnation.)

Comment: Isn't there usually a distinction between heresy and idolatry? Sabellianism is certainly heresy according to the Rambam's opinion (and likely others) but is it idolatry?

Comment: What hodofhod says is exactly what this question is all about. Also is being heretic sin? Sabellianism is basically saying that the almighty G-d can appear to humans in many forms, including incarnating as a human.

Comment: Not all agree with the Rambam that believing God has a body makes one a heretic.

Comment: Is believing that God has a body (or can incarnate) a sin? Also is being heretical sin?