# Is it halachically acceptable for a Jew to be a Zen monk, as Leonard Cohen was?

Tags: halacha

With the news today of Leonard Cohen (z"l), I was surprised to find out he was ordained as a Zen monk as well as seeing Judaism as his religion. [I read](http://hollowverse.com/leonard-cohen/):

> He’s carried his Jewish faith with him throughout his life, regularly
>   observing the Sabbath.3 Even after he started studying Zen Buddhism he
>   said,
>
> I’m not looking for a new religion. I’m quite happy with the old one,
>   with Judaism.4
>
> And Cohen’s study of Zen wasn’t just a weekend project. He lived at a
>   Buddhist monastery for five years5 and became a fully ordained monk in
>   1996.6
>
> About reconciling Buddhism and Judaism, Cohen said,
>
> Well, for one thing, in the tradition of Zen that I’ve practiced,
>   there is no prayerful worship and there is no affirmation of a deity.
>   So theologically there is no challenge to any Jewish belief.7

Personally I am of the view that we have to decide for ourselves what G!d requires of us, but I was curious what the halachic position would be on this situation.

Comment: I think a better question to ask, is which elements of Zen Buddhism, if any, would be forbidden for a Jew to subscribe to or practice. That way we can avoid the True-Scotsman situation of who the real Buddhists are.

Comment: I don't know enough about buddhism to know for sure but this might be a dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40845/759

Answer (score 5):

One ritual performed in Zen sanghas after a sit has concluded involves bowing down, optionally making full prostration, in the direction of a statue of the Buddha. The Zen description of this ritual is that they are [not bowing to an external entity, but to the Buddha within](http://howtopracticezen.com/advanced-zen/prostrations/). Whether this means bowing down to an idol could be open for debate.

Before a Zen sit begins, the doan lights a stick of incense below the statue. It's said that the incense is a [sacred offering to the Buddha](https://www.buddhagroove.com/why-do-we-burn-incense-in-buddhist-rituals/). It seems plausible to interpret this activity as offering incense to an idol if one sees the Buddha statue at the front of every sangha as an idol.