# Prayer in the "House of the One"

Tags: halacha, synagogue, christianity, architecture-design, islam

I recently read [this article](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-27872551) on the new  "House of the One".  The building will feature three separated spaces for prayer: a mosque, a church, and a synagogue.  There will be a central courtyard, but each religious space will be completely free of the icons/characteristics of the other.  Is it permissible to daven in the synagogue part of the "House of the One"?

NOTE: I am aware that the rabbi who will be overseeing the shul part of the "House of the One", Tovia ben Chorin, is a Reform rabbi, and that there is an entirely separate issue about the permissibility of davening in a Reform shul.  However, I am asking this question to see about the issues with the mosque and the church in the same complex, not with davening Reform, so for the sake of argument, please pretend that the shul is Orthodox.

Inspired in part by this question:[Praying in "multifaith spaces" in airports and other institutions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34507/praying-in-multifaith-spaces-in-airports-and-other-institutions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming one would be allowed to pray in the synagogue if it weren't attached to the House of the One, I don't see why not. It shouldn't be any different than the chapel area at JFK where there are three separate rooms next to each other for Muslims, Christians, and Jews and the chaplains share an office.

Answer (score 0):

In the first letter in Community covenant and commitment, Rabbi Soloveitchik writes against using interfaith chapels. At the end of the piece he adds on an idea against the practice which seems to have significance to your question. He says that the actual building of different houses of worship convey different expressions of religiousness. The church with its vaulted ceilings fits the vristion worship of beatitude and otherworldliness, as contrasted to the humble shul which asserts itself of direct concretedialog between God and man. It seems that whoever builds even the separate synagogue would have to be in tune to our version of worship.