# Is it prohibited to say a bracha near an idol?

Tags: halacha, blessing, avodah-zarah

In the trades, some times home owners will have statues of Buddha or catholic stuff like saints and such.

I've heard some rule idolatry today is not the same as before.

Are there any prohibitions for reciting a blessing and eating near them?

Comment: IIRC not only is it prohibited in front of an idol, but even a picture that has one. Years ago, I attended a mincha minyan in a kosher restaurant in my building. On the wall, was a huge painting of some Hawaiian beach. The front of the picture had a totem pole. This was colored black so that people could daven in the room.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34507/5275

Comment: very similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28394/759