# May one buy wine from a Muslim

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, grapes-wine

If a person were to go to a Muslim wine shop and found wine only handled by a Muslim. Is the wine forbidden? I would think not because Muslims are monotheistic and even if they would use the wine in a religious ritual it was used in a manner that isn't עבודה זרה, because Islam is monotheistic

Comment: The Rambam ruled that such wine is forbidden for consumption but permitted for other benefits ([*Hil. Ma'achalos Asuros* 11:7](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=5&hilchos=28&perek=11&halocha=7), see the end of [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26355) for an excerpt).

Comment: According to Sharia, it is assur to derive benefit from alcohol, much as it is assur for us to derive benefit from treif.

Comment: Indeed.  http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2528388/Not-just-u-turn-M-amp-S-u-turn-Now-chain-apologises-Muslim-check-girl-refused-sell-alcohol-customer.html

Comment: Sharia however doesn't prohibit the sales of alcohol. Only consumption of alcohol by a Muslim is forbidden, and by the way Sunni Muslims don't say that a person has to be Muslim so everything fits in nicely lol

Answer (score 6):

(By the way -- a sealed bottle of kosher wine can be handled by anyone, hence I am allowed to walk into any store in the planet and buy a sealed bottle of wine marked "OU kosher" [assuming they didn't counterfeit it, assuming the seal is intact, etc.] regardless of the faith of the shopkeeper. I'm assuming you mean wine that was handled by Muslims before/after it was sealed in the bottle.)

There were two reasons that "non-Jewish wine" is prohibited: out of concern it may have been used in a pagan libation, and to prevent extra socialization that would lead to intermarriage. The latter reason causes wine handled by *any* non-Jew, no matter their belief, to be prohibited from drinking.

Would you be allowed to *sell* such a bottle though? Sephardic opinions hold that it was categorically prohibited as well. Ashkenazic rabbis interpret that there's only a prohibition on selling non-kosher wine if it was plausibly handled by pagans. Hence if you have a kosher wine shop and by mistake they shipped you a case of non-kosher wine (let's assume it's coming from a non-pagan country), the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch allows you to sell it, you don't have to pour it all out. (I'm assuming the circumstances were that you couldn't get a refund...) Sephardic authorities might be stricter.

Comment: "a sealed bottle of kosher wine can be handled by anyone" Source?

Answer (score 0):

At schul there is an english copy of the halachos of the Ben ish Chai. Unlike a young child of idolators, a young child of muslims does not render wine nesech.

If the winery was manned by a three year olds, one may use the wine.