# Does Judaism Regard Muslims as B'nai Noah (Righteous Gentiles)?

Tags: islam, noahidism

Does Judaism Regard Muslims as B'nai Noah (Righteous Gentiles)?

https://youtu.be/udYM4FuYdiA

Comment: Welcome to mi yodeya Sean! Thanks for sharing the question.

Comment: I haven't watched the video yet, but shouldn't it answer your question?

Comment: The title of the video is *Muslim: Does Judaism Regard Muslims as B’nai Noah (Righteous Gentiles)? Rabbi Tovia Singer Responds* He is a valid source and would be a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who follows the 7 laws of Noah is a B’nai Noah.

The issue is usually worshiping false gods as the other 6 are relatively uncommon these days. Worshiping of Allah is NOT considered idol worship is Allah is, even by Muslims the god of Abraham.

Comment: Hi Morons, welcome to Mi Yodeya. Remember that no one here knows you that we should trust your assertions, so it's always best to [edit] in sources or the like in order to back up your answer. For instance, why does someone claiming to be worshipping the god of Abraham make it so? If I declare my cereal box to be the god of Abraham and then worship it, that would seemingly be Avoda Zara.

Comment: @doubleAA the cereal box would be a pesel because it has  a form. Also the Ramabam gave classes on Islam to the local Muslims.

Comment: also relevant info here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26328/jews-allowed-to-pray-and-join-muslim-congregation-in-mosques-and-experiences