# Did the Ritva state that Islam is idolatry?

Tags: avodah-zarah, islam

Is it the case that Ritva stated that Islam is idolatry?

I have heard that while the RAMBAM viewed Islam as not idolatry, there have been many rabbis throughout the generations, before and some after, that have viewed it as idolatry.  Is that the case?

Comment: Also related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26328/jews-allowed-to-pray-and-join-muslim-congregation-in-mosques-and-experiences/26355#26355

Comment: @Dov Is there an exact source given there?

Comment: It mentions the Ran that says that as they bow in their mosques that it is a form of idolatry, as mentioned in the Tzitz Eliezer...