# Does Jewish scripture show a preference between non-belief or erroneous belief?

Tags: gentiles, ikarim

Obviously, Judaism maintains that it is best to follow Judaism or, for gentiles, the Noachide laws.  But I'm curious as to whether, according to Jewish scripture, it is preferable to not believe in G-d, or to believe the wrong things about G-d.  That is to say, is it better to be an atheist, or a Christian, Buddhist, Hindu, Shintoist, etc?  This question is about *belief*, not *practice*.

I'm also assuming that the nonbeliever in question is a good person.  He or she treats other people with respect and compassion, cares for the less fortunate and the afflicted, and is in all respects an admirable human being.  He or she simply doesn't believe in G-d.

Note:  I'm deliberately leaving out Islam, because [I have been led to understand](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6004/if-christianity-is-avodah-zarah-and-islam-is-not-why-has-the-christian-world-tr) that, at least theoretically, Islam is considered to be preferable to the other non-Jewish options.

Comment: "Judaism maintains that it is best to be Jewish" ??? I don't find that obvious...

Comment: As a new member of Mi Yodeya Wad, the quality and diversity of your questions is quite impressive. Judaism does not consider it best to be Jewish. A basic tenant of Judaism is that each individual person and each nation has a specific role to play in God's plan. Judaism does perceive believers in monotheism--especially followers of the Noahide Laws---as on a higher spiritual level than pagans and heathens. Sincere followers of monotheastic faiths are assured a place in heaven. Ignorance of the law, as in secular courts, is no vindication............

Comment: ..........Non-belief at all (even in pseudo-faith such as secular humanism)? That I'm not sure.

Comment: AS JJLL said, Judaism doesn't actually maintain that it is best for *everyone* to be Jewish.  Judaism does expect *Jews* to follow Jewish law and tradition, but for everybody else, it is enough to follow the seven laws of Noah, which include a prohibition on idolatry.  I'm guessing you didn't know about that and would rather not base a question on a faulty premise, so I'm going to make an edit -- but if you have any objection to that edit or I've misunderstood your intent, please roll back or make another edit.

Comment: One of the things that you will notice around this site is that there is an incredible diversity of views that not only exist, but are considered "basic". To cite one source about the relative merits of Jews and gentiles, Maimonides writes in Laws of Shmita V'yovel [13:12](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/7713n.htm) וְלֹא שֵׁבֶט לֵוִי בִּלְבָד, אֵלָא כָּל אִישׁ וְאִישׁ מִכָּל בָּאֵי הָעוֹלָם אֲשֶׁר נָדְבָה רוּחוֹ אוֹתוֹ וֶהֱבִינוֹ מַדָּעוֹ לְהִבָּדֵל לַעֲמֹד לִפְנֵי ה' לְשָׁרְתוֹ וּלְעָבְדוֹ לְדֵעָה אֶת ה'...הֲרֵי זֶה נִתְקַדַּשׁ קֹדֶשׁ קֳדָשִׁים, וְיִהְיֶה ה' חֶלְקוֹ וְנַחֲלָתוֹ לְעוֹלָם

Comment: Translation: "Not just the tribe of Levi, but rather every person of all the inhabitants of the Earth, whose spirit moved him and whose intelligence gave him the understanding to separate to stand before God and to serve and minister to Him...behold he is sanctified with the utmost sanctity and God will be his portion and heritage for all eternity..." His language clearly refers to non-Jews as well as Jews. All have the potential to reach this exalted status. (in his view).

Comment: @DoubleAA, Monica, et al:  I meant that Judaism naturally views Judaism as correct (which is why Jews are Jewish), and I assumed that the natural correlation to this would be that, all other things being equal, it would be ideal if everyone realized that Judaism was the best option.  Not that people should be compelled to become Jewish, only that it would be nice if everyone *chose* to be Jewish after deciding that it was superior to the other alternatives.  I would be very happy to be proven wrong on this.  I always thought that each religion sees itself as better than the others.

Comment: @WadCheber Take a look a Deuteronomy 4:15-20 it seems to be implying that only the Jews have to follow God, and that God alloted, or chose, or gave the sun moon and stars for other religions to worship.

Comment: @WadCheber This may be a semantic issue, but "Judaism" (in the sense of what Jews practice and what Noahides practice) thinks that non-Jews who follow the seven Noahide laws are perfectly fine in that capacity and are not even encouraged to convert to Judaism (the kind that Jews practice). This does entail their acceptance of the general Jewish enterprise as the correct one (as it applies differently for Jews and non-Jews), but saying that 'non-Jews should ideally accept Judaism' sounds quite off to our ears.

Comment: @Aaron See Megilla 9b. The ability to read into those verses the interpretation you present is noted, rejected and cautioned against about as early as you can find in Jewish sources. (It's true that our Septuagint does not have the listed change TTBOMK.)

Comment: I happily stand corrected:)

Comment: @JJLL - You raise a good point.  Question edited to specify that we're talking about a person who treats others kindly, and is generally a very decent human being.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I understand now.  Thank you for explaining it to me.  And more generally, thank you to everyone on the site for being patient with my incessant questions.  I'm really, REALLY enjoying the opportunity to learn from all of you.

Comment: @JJLL - I seriously appreciate your kind words.  I hope I can make a useful contribution to the site, but I can't hope to give back as much as I have taken.

Comment: @JJLL Great point, could you put it in an answer with some citations? I feel it essentially answers the question. Also, what about monotheistic religions that require the adherents to violate the Noahide law by blaspheming (e.g. claiming that a man is G-d or setting up saints as idols). I expect your point is that if the sum of their life is toward charity and generally obeying the other commandments judgement will go in their favor, but if you can illustrate from the Tanakh or Talmud that would certainly get my +1. As to doubt that such a unbelieving Tsadik exists, have the sages spoken?

Comment: @MonicaCellio - In keeping with your reasoning behind editing the question, would it be better if I rephrased the title?  Perhaps "heterodox belief" (literally "different belief") would be better than "erroneous belief"?

Comment: The question "Does scripture prefer orthodoxy?" is quite different than "Does scripture prefer misinformed beliefs about monotheism over non-theism?". The problem with the question is more about its concern with belief over practice. Judaism is concerned with practice and very much less so with belief. I think what JJLL was saying is that the final judgement will only take into account what one does in this life and not what they say they thought. That is why there isn't the emphasis on a conversion experience that you find in Christianity.

Comment: @Subcreation On a point of minor detail, not every Christian denomination puts emphasis on the conversion experience, and in fact, most don't.  It's the evangelicals who focus on conversion experiences and personal relationship with Jesus.  The vast majority of denominations focus much more on belief and behavior.  And I wasn't suggesting that I would change the question to "is orthodoxy better than heterodoxy".  I was just asking if it would be better to say "heterodoxy" as opposed "erroneous belief", because the latter might be too judgmental.

Comment: @WadCheber You might say "…non-belief or jewish belief". Perhaps I misunderstood what MonicaCellio and JJLL were saying, but I thought the point wasn't that the beliefs of Judaism aren't held to be correct, but essentially that it allows room for admitting followers of other religions to HaOlam Haba based on keeping the Law.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27127/discussion-between-subcreation-and-wad-cheber).

Answer (score 2):

As acknowledged in the question, Judaism only requires that non-jews keep the seven Noachide laws (plus some miscellaneous laws which are beyond the scope of this answer). Seeing as the first of these is the prohibition against idolatry, it is clear that belief in any polytheistic religion is definitely a problem. That the prohibition extends to belief in addition to action can be seen from the Rambam in [Hilchot Melachim 9:2](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Kings_and_Wars.9.2?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all).

What about atheism? Is atheism less problematic?

Jews (according to most classic opinions) have an explicit mitzvah to believe in God. There is no such mitzvah amongst the seven Noachide laws. Only the prohibition against idolatry. In the past, I inferred from this that there would be no problem with a non-jew being atheist. After all, one can be atheist and keep all of the seven Noachide laws. The problem with this is a halacha found in the Rambam, [Hilchot Melachim 8:11](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Kings_and_Wars.8.11?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all), which states that a non-jew who keeps the seven Noachide laws because of his own moral calculations instead of because of God's commanding them doesn't get *full* credit for them (note that there are two variants of this halacha. See the Frankel ed. The above point stands according to both though). We thus see that the behaviour of a non-jew who doesn't believe in God is deficient regardless of how good his behaviour is. Apparently then, belief in God is some sort of prerequisite to the seven Noachide laws. This would also explain why the Rambam mentions this halacha immediately before listing the seven Noachide laws and their various details.

It appears then that atheism would also be a problem for non-jews, albeit a less severe one than polytheism.

What about Christianity* which professes to be monotheistic? The classic sources generally think that Christianity is idolatrous, for example, the Rambam explicitly says so in Hilchot Ma'achalot Assurot 11:7 (see the Franked ed. for the uncensored version) as well as in other places. There is however an often quoted [Tosofot to Sanhedrin 63b](http://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Sanhedrin.63b.15.1?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) which states that it is permissible to force a christian to make an oath with the name of God because the christian is only "associating" (*shituf*) God with his idolatrous beliefs and this is permissible for non-jews to do. There is significant discussion regarding whether Tosofot means that *shituf* is generally permitted for non-jews or only in the context of making oaths. To summarise then, according to one school of thought, Christianity is as problematic as any polytheistic religion while according to others, there may be no problem depending on how you interpret the aforementioned Tosofot.

Even though the question explicitly excluded Islam, it seems appropriate to deal with it here anyway because it will give us an insight into other religions in general. Classically, Islam has been assumed to not be idolatrous. This can for example be seen in the previously mentioned Rambam, [Hilchot Ma'achalot Assurot 11:7](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Forbidden_Foods.11.7?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all). This however only addresses one side of the issue. From a theological perspective, Islam is apparently not idolatrous. Does this make it into an acceptable belief system for non-jews? The answer is unequivocally no. See the Rambam in [Hilchot Melachim 10:9](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Kings_and_Wars.10.9?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) where he explicitly brings a prohibition for non-jews to create their own religions to serve God. In his language - אין מניחין אותן לחדש דת ולעשות מצות לעצמן מדעתן - or in english - "we do not allow them to create a religion or to create mitzvot for themselves based on their opinions". As such, assuming that Muhammed wasn't actually a prophet of God, it turns out that subscribing to Islam and in fact any non-jewish religion would also be problematic for non-jews.

To summarise, from best to worst, we have the following types of belief in God for non-jews:

1. Belief in God as described by Judaism (i.e. singular, omnipotent, omniscient, etc.) without subscribing to another religion
2. Belief in God as described by a non-jewish genuinely monotheistic religion such as Islam.
3. Atheism
4. Belief in God as described by Christianity according to *some* opinions
5. Polytheism (and Christianity according to other opinions)

(Note: There may be some room to argue for swapping the order of 3 and 4)

*If I am not mistaken, different denominations of Christianity can have very different beliefs about the divinity of Jesus and other potentially idolatrous beliefs. I'm not familiar with any classic sources which bother to distinguish between the denominations though so I have no way of categorising which denominations are less problematic and which are more.

Comment: Rambam doesnt say "that a non-jew who keeps the seven Noachide laws because of his own moral calculations instead of because of God's commanding them doesn't get credit for them" He says that he does not receive the _particular_ credit discussed in that halacha. It would seem fairly unlikely that according to Rambam an atheist may as well devite his life to theft and murder since even were to he refrain it would count for nothing.

Comment: Although this is a nice collection of sources, the only part of the answer which directly addressed the crux of the question; atheism vs. polytheism, seems to be an unfounded assumption at best.

Comment: "As such, assuming that Muhammed wasn't actually a prophet of God (a reasonable assumption given that many of his teachings contradict those contained within Judaism)" this is not the place for a presentation of why you dont believe Islam to be true. The question is how Judaism would view the relative merits of different beliefs that are incorrect from a Jewish perspective.

Comment: "it turns out that subscribing to Islam and in fact any non-jewish religion would also be problematic for non-jews." Where do you see any problem with subscribing to beliefs? I only see a problem with certain _practices_.

Comment: "In his language "they are to keep their own mitzvot and not innovate at all" This is not the Rambam's own language. Rambam did not speak English. Furthermore, he doesnt say this (at least in the cited halacha) in any other language either. The closest thing he says is עכו"ם שעסק בתורה חייב מיתה לא יעסוק אלא בשבע מצות שלהן בלבד the latter clause לא יעסוק אלא בשבע מצות שלהן obviously means in context that he should not _study_ Torah pertaining to other mitzvos; not that he should not perform them.

Comment: Lastly, it should be noted that Rambam does not limit non-Jews' religous activity to the 7 Noahide laws. In a responsum he presents a carte blanche encouragement for non-Jews to perform mitzvos, saying that they receive merit for this just like any אינו מצווה ועושה; person who fulfills a mitzva which he is not commanded in.

Comment: Just to conclude on a positive note, this answer is a well assembled collection of sources, which I respect, and my criticism should not be viewed as ad hominem. I look forward to seeing you around the site and am sure that if you stick around you will continue to make many valuable contributions. Hope to see you around.

Comment: @mevaqesh Thanks for the feedback! I've incorporated the points which I understood into the answer. I'm confused by your comment that H. Melachim 10:9 doesn't prohibit non-jewish religions. The halacha starts with the issur of limmud torah, then moves onto the issur of keeping shabbat, and ends with the issur of creating religions. I've included the complete halacha in the next comment. Are you perhaps using a Rambam with an unusual numbering for the halachot?

Comment: עכו"ם שעסק בתורה חייב מיתה לא יעסוק אלא בשבע מצות שלהן בלבד וכן עכו"ם ששבת אפילו ביום מימות החול אם עשאהו לעצמו כמו שבת חייב מיתה ואין צריך לומר אם עשה מועד לעצמו כללו של דבר אין מניחין אותן לחדש דת ולעשות מצות לעצמן מדעתן אלא או יהיה גר צדק ויקבל כל המצות או יעמוד בתורתו ולא יוסיף ולא יגרע ואם עסק בתורה או שבת או חדש דבר מכין אותו ועונשין אותו ומודיעין אותו שהוא חייב מיתה על זה אבל אינו נהרג.

Comment: @mevaqesh I am aware of the שו׳׳ת which says that non-jews can keep mitzvot and get reward for them and it is in fact the plain reading of the very next halacha in the Rambam (H. Melachim 10:10). I don't think I ever implied otherwise and I don't see the relevance to the question. Also, I don't understand in which sense the question is left unanswered. I cover atheism, polytheism and christianity thoroughly. I also note that your comments only strengthen my conclusion. Please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know p, the only modern denominations of Christianity that don't fully accept Jesus as divine are the JWs and the "Jews for Jesus" type groups (including the modern Ebionites).

Comment: @Meh - The Wikipedia page for the Noachide laws says that the first one is "Do not deny G-d", which seems to cover atheism.

Comment: @Meh See my above 6 comments, but I will try to reiterate: Your only piece of evidence regarding the status of an atheistic gentile, whose status vis-à-vis a polytheist was the crux of the question, was Rambam's formulation in Hil. Melachim 8:11 this addresses one who performs the commandments independently; not an atheist. (although atheists would be by definition a subset of this category). Furthermore, we see nothing here about his status vis-à-vis a polytheist. Accordingly, (aside from other objections which I will reiterate) the question is not answered.

Comment: @meh regarding Rambm H. Melachim 10:9, you wrote that this would prohibit one from subscribing to Islam. I assumed that subscribe meant "express or feel agreement with an idea or proposal". This is an intellectual activity. Rambam, on the other hand, is addressing physical activities; the performance of new rituals.

Comment: Regarding Hil. Melachim 10:10, I am not so sure that is the plain reading. R. Moshe Feinstein, who evidently did not see the responsum understand the Rambam as referencing the _mistaken notion_ that it would result in reward. (For this reason I referenced the responsum which is is unequivocal). Regardless, his encouragement for gentiles to practice _mitzvos_ that they are not commanded in contradicts what you wrote (although it appears it has been edited out) that Rambam writes that they should only practice their own 7 commandments.

Comment: All this aside, it is worth repeating that this still has not provided anything in the way of evidence that polytheism is worse than atheism. In fact I think that Rambam would probably disagree (based on his statement in Maamar t'ciyas hameisim that heresy is worse than idolatry. If I have time I will research this and post it as an answer).

Answer (score 2):

There is a dispute at to whether שיתוף (believing in G-d AND another power; the trinity included) is permitted for gentiles. See [Is Christianity Avodah Zara?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89/is-christianity-avodah-zara) for the differing opinions. There's no need to go through it again. I heard from a Rabbi who's actively involved in spreading knowledge of the 7 Noahide laws that most contemporary rabbis hold that שיתוף is allowed, although not preferable).

As for whether gentiles are required to believe in G-d, while many versions of the 7 Noahide laws say not to deny G-d, others say not to do idolatry instead. https://books.google.com.au/books?id=UEzgAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA591&dq=Tosefta+Avodah+Zarah+noah&hl=en&sa=X&ei=np7zVKTPJ-3fsAShq4LwBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Tosefta%20Avodah%20Zarah%20noah&f=false It explains here that believing in G-d is likely included in the law against idolatry, and even if it's not, it's been clarified in later commentaries.
I'm not aware of anyone who says that they don't need to believe in G-d. Either way, Maimonides, even though he counts idolatry (kings and wars 9.1), he still says they need to believe that G-d commanded them through Moses (ibid 8.14)
[Note: Idolatry is worship, (Hebrew: avodah zarah, strange service. So for your question about belief, not practise, you wouldn't have a problem of idolatry. I'm just demonstrating that believing in G-d is necessary.)

(Additionally, Abraham fought hard to get gentiles to recognise G-d (I can bring sources if necessary).)

So, to summarise, best is to believe in G-d, believing that he is the One and Only power.

Next, שיתוף, (including believing in the trinity). While some say that this is allowed for gentiles, others say it's not.

Next, atheism, which it seems everyone, or at the very least, nearly everyone, holds isn't alright for gentiles.

Comment: "Next, polytheistic (including believing in the trinity). While some say that this is allowed for gentiles, others say it's not." Do you mean that polytheism is permitted for gentiles? Why inst that _Avodah Zarah_. If you mean only that trinity is possibly permitted, but not full polytheism, then the question; of polytheism vs. atheism remains unanswered. Either way, you have a problem. The only reason I am not downvoting because the other answer contains even more mistakes.

Comment: @mevaqesh I edited my answer. I don't see the difference between idolatry and shittuf, except that with shittuf you also believe in Hashem, but there are definitely many opinions who hold shittuf I alright. Maybe it is idolatry, but it's allowed if they also believe in Hashem. I don't know

Comment: To repeat clearly: you have not demonstrated that atheism is worse that idolatry; only than _shittuf_ which may be permitted in the first place. The main thrust of the question was about atheism vs. Avodah Zarah.

Comment: BTW the link to google books does not display. GB sayd it wither is a page that cannot be displayed, or the viewing limit has been reached.

Comment: @mevaqesh The page is working for me. And it's quite interesting that you say the question is about avodah zarah, when the question says "this question is about belief, not practise", avodah zarah is practise

Comment: @mevaqesh Now I realize, shittuf and avodah zarah are actually quite different.

Answer (score -1):

generally speaking Christianity is better than Atheism since it's based on the Tanach. (though it could be exploited by bad people as we saw in the spanish inquisition). Here's a source.

> Kovetz Maamarim 69 - The holy Chafetz Chaim would say: "if the torah
>   study has stopped then perforce the faith will also stop. And without
>   faith the world cannot endure". This is explained in the verse "only
>   there is no fear of God in this place, and they will kill me because
>   of my wife" (Gen.20:11). The intent of "only", is that there is
>   nothing in the world which has the power to hold back the animal in
>   man besides the fear of God. In our times (world war II) where denial
>   of God has spread throughout the world, human beings have become
>   snakes which bite each other, and the proper (metukan) countries among the
>   nations are those which believe in the holy writings (Tanach).

Comment: Your quote says that belief in God is good. It also says that belief in holy writings is good. It does not say that belief in God and holy writings is more good than a lack of belief in polytheism, which was the OP's question. The only line which answers the OP's question is the first unsourced line.

Comment: Where did you get this translation?

Comment: @MonicaCellio mevaqesh keeps editing my posts and adding "translation my own". i am trying to keep my name anonymous here and could add a link to my site instead if this is required. can you clarify the policy for this. thanks.

Comment: If you have some desire to say to remain to anonymous, that is perfectly understandable. Simply saying so is much more productive than deleting sources included in your posts by other users without explanation. | I dont know when you decided to go anonymous, but note that you yourself repeatedly reference the site, and  refer to it as yourself. | None of this seems too relevant since you can admit that the translation is your own (assuming it isn't plagarised from some other source) without linking to your site.

Comment: @mevaqesh let's hear what monica cellio says on this. in the meantime stop editing my posts please. i can try to add a link to my site. but i dont want people (who know who i am) to think i am just trying to get traffic.

Comment: More productive than a link to the site is simply identifying the translator.