# Is friendship with Christians and other idolaters permitted?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah

Does Torah permit having friends who are Christians/Muslims/other forms of Avodah Zarah?

Comment: Islam is not considered a form of Avodah Zarah, so you can scratch that one off your list

Comment: Important to the premise of this question: [Is Christianity Avodah Zara?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89/is-christianity-avodah-zara), [Is Islam Avodah Zara?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75284/is-islam-avodah-zara), [Avodah Zarah in other religions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12229/avodah-zarah-in-other-religions).

Comment: Similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14324/759

Comment: @JoshK I am surprised you don't know that Islam is Avodah Zarah. Please see: https://youtu.be/DV2CSEd3lbA

Comment: @Dan Weisberg the Rambam and most major poskim hold that it is not....there are malokets about many things but I don't think this is one of them

Comment: @JoshK Either way, it's a false religion

Comment: @Dan Weisberg it's the only false religion that is indisputably not Avodah Zarah, which is a fascinating place to be, halachicaly speaking

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Talmud says that if a non-Jew is destitute, we must provide charity; if ill, we tend to them; if they die without relatives, we bury them.

This applies even to downright pagans, and certainly to non-Jews who are not pagans. (Muslims definitely fall into the latter category.)

There are concerns of becoming overly chummy with non-Jews as it can lead to intermarriage; Rabbi Aaron Soloveichik remarked that the ban here was on "fellowship" -- "hey let's drink together", but never on true *friendship*.

There will always be some distance as we don't want to blur the lines of our faith, but that doesn't mean "you can't have non-Jews as friends." The Talmud describes the warm relationship between Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi and a Roman official named Antoninus, for example.

Comment: Page citations, please.