# Why is the idea of sefirot not shituf?

Tags: avodah-zarah, mysticism-kabbalah

Why are the sefirot not considered a problem of Shituf? Is there anything wrong with believing in sefirot?

Comment: I must say, the original question was asked better :) I disagreed with the previous closing.

Comment: There is probably a middle ground that would be universally superior, including the reference to the Riva"sh, the difficulty with _shituf_, and a reference to the concept of _s'firos_ to which the question refers, while excluding the Christian context.

Comment: ... or, at least, a brief explanation of what _s'firos_ and _shituf_ are and a reason the asker thinks the former might be an instance of the latter.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30015/god-is-fire-trying-to-source-an-analogy-for-prayer

Answer (score 9):

The idea behind the Sefirot is as follows.

1. Sefirot are creations, they are not Gd.
2. Sefirot are not physical creations, but rather created "processes", for the sake of human sanity, they are described as "things", but they are really "methods".
3. The basic rule in Kabalah is that there is the Ein_Sof (The no end) which is unknowable, unfathomable, and unable to be spoken about.  The ein sof (which is equally nothing, and infinite) created the 10 Sefirot.  The 10 sefirot were thus used to then create the rest of creation.

Therefor, the Sefiort are not shituf because they are a step away from Gd.

However!... According to many davening to the sefirot is 100% shituf. (No different than davening to Angels to ancestors)
One must be careful when asking for the "unification" of Ykvk and the Shechinah, that they have in mind the idea that they are asking Gd to unifiy the two concepts and methods to have the same outcome. They are not actually davening to the emanations.

It could be argued by some, that a lack of understanding could lead one to have Shituf if they distinguish between YKVK, Elokim, etc in their davening.  To put it another way, one might ask why the various names of Gd is not shituf.

Comment: If it is no different than davening to angels, then if one holds that davening to angels (or deceased ancestors) is permitted, is it also permitted to daven to sefirot?

Comment: I don't know, because I don't know who permits such a thing. :)

Comment: That is, I don't know the reasoning why such a thing would be permitted to know if that same reasoning would apply to Ykvk or Shechina from a kabbalistic understanding of those terms.

Comment: Well R. Moshe (OH 5:43) discusses praying to the deceased and seems to be permissive even though he doesn't do it himself. And it certainly is a very widespread custom to pray to deceased ancestors for their intercession. And the Minchas Elazar (1:68) allows it also.

Comment: As far as I understand they did not allow to pray to the deceased as an intercession, only in the merit of, and at the place of.... however my understanding is not correct. Apparently what I have heard is revisionism.  You can read about the debate here:  http://www.biu.ac.il/JS/JSIJ/2-2003/Malkiel.pdf

Comment: What is a "created process" or "method"? If it isn't a (meta)physical object, then is it like a [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_operating_procedure)? Sounds more like a list of steps. How does creation apply to a non-thing? Wouldn't "decided" or "declared" or "wrote" be more appropriate for a SOP?

Answer (score 4):

Someone asked the [Rivash](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19989&st=&pgnum=77) this question. He answered that a Mekubal told him that one prays only to Hashem himself. "Asking" the sefiros is like asking a king to give you something through a channel. The Rivash answered that he would rather pray to Hashem directly and let him decide how to give him his request.

The 3rd Rebbe of Lubavitch explained in [Derech Mitzvosecha](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16082&st=&pgnum=104) and [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16082&st=&pgnum=110) that the sefiros are not one with Hashem's essence, they are the revelation of Hashem, and even that revelation is one, just the "vessels" change the light into different forms.

Comment: is there any time when we directly ask the sefirot for something during prayer?

Comment: when asking for the unification of YkvK and Shechinah, you are asking for the unification of Keter and Malchut.

Comment: I don't understand. "even that revelation is one": which revelation? Do you mean all 10 sefirot are 'one'? If so, then how are they 10? "into different forms": how can something have different forms, but be 'one'? Isn't that what Shittuf is? How does that answer the question then? This answer needs clarification IMO.

Comment: Also, this a bad summary of the Rivash. The Mekubal in the Rivash's teshuva says that no one ever asks the sefirot anything, but when one has kavana for a certain sefira at different times while asking God, it is like asking a king to appoint a certain officer to deal with one's issue (ie, the Attorney General if you have a fight, or the Head Chef if you need food).

Comment: Also, we don't know anyone asked the Rivash this question. We know _he_ looked around and thought all the Mekubalim were Kofrim so he asked his good Mekubal friend who told him an answer which he says might technically work but is skeptical about, and concludes that it is better not to study Kabbalah at all.

Answer (score 3):

The Mitteler Rebbe of Lubavitch wrote a book called Shaar HaYichud. In this sefer the M.R. explains the entire "Seder Histalshelus" from Atzmus Ohr Ein Sof (Essence of the Light that is Infinite) to Malchus of Malchus of Asiyah.

Sefiros are methods (as stated above) for which Hashem (Ein Sof) brings the entire creation into existence. A primary source of source for Seder Histalshelus is "Chesed" (ch. 11)

Note Birkas Shema that we say "Kulam B'Chochma Asysah"

Through Hashem's names and Sefiros, creation is created Yesh M'Ayin, and it functions.

Note Birkas Shema "U'Tuvo, M'Chadesh BKol Yom Tamid Maseh Bereshis"

Kabbalah states that we channel Hashem's Hashpa in blessings we make using different sefiros. Each of the names of Hashem connects to a different Sefira.

The Blessings of Shemonah Esrei all connect to different sefiros and during prayer you are able to draw down Hashem's Hashpa through those sefiros.

With all this said, a person who does not understand this process as well as what will be said below will be worshiping something other then Hashem C"V. If it is actual Avodah Zarah would be up to debate. Shituf would only apply if you actually understand what "Chochmah" is and really believe that Chochmah has to power to create something for you. Outside of bowing to Idols, slaughtering sacrifices to them, and worshiping them in the way they are worshiped ie: Throwing rocks are Mercury" it is not avodah zarah proper to pray to sefiros since this is not their primary form of worship. Regardless it is foolishness and one of the unfortunate side effects of learning Kabbalah without a real understanding of what you are learning.

---

Once the blessing formula is broken down "al pi Kabbalah" it is easy to see how the process works.

Baruch - The root is נרך which means to kneel. Baruch is not just "Blessed are you" but it is a request to bring down blessing. From where?

Atah - Atah represents Atzmus Ein Sof. It is higher thatn all other names, including YKVK. We ask that Hashem (Ein Sof) draw down blessing for us. Through?

YKVH - Hashems name that connects to Tiferes which bridges Chesed and Gevurah. Its mercy. This name can be connected to different siferos for different blessings and bring down the blessing through that.

Example: Shemonah Esrei Blessing 4 "Chonen HaDoas" is connected to the level of Chochmah since we are asking Hashem to instill us with Wisdom, Understanding, and Knowledge.

---

One of the reasons why the Rivash rejected this approach to prayer is how it could easily result in undesirable affects.

The average Jew should focus on Pirush HaMilos (Simple meaning of the words) and not concern themselves with Sefiros.

The Alter Rebbe writes in his siddur that if one is not able to use kabbalistic kavanah during prayer he should have a general kavanah that his prayers should be heard by Hashem and lifted up with all the Kavanahs in their place.

Comment: +1. While someone with a background in Chassidus and/or Kabbalah may understand most of what you bring here, it might be helpful to clarify and explain some of the concepts you mention, i.e. "Kulam B'Chochma Asisah".

Comment: @HodofHod Those non translated parts are blessings of Shema. It would do all reads are great service to their spiritual development to understand and study the words of davening, especially Shema and Shemonah Esrei. Kulam B'Chochma Asysah means " In Wisdom Hashem created everything" U'Tuvo, M'Chadesh BKol Yom Tamid Maseh Bereshis" means "in goodness Hashem make new each day, continually this is the work of creation. I will always translate Lashon Kodesh in the future.

Comment: @mochinrechavim I did not refer to translation, but rather the kabbalistic _idea_ of "kulam b'chochma asisah", as brought down in the beginning of Tanya, for example. (That is, that it means more than G-d creating the world wisely, he did it with "Chochmah".) I assumed that this idea was what you referred to, correct?

Comment: @HodofHod Correct. In Ch. 8 of Shaar HaYichud the Mitteler Rebbe discusses this idea and mentions two opinions that "Bereshit” is translated by Targum Yonatan as “B’Chochmeta - with Wisdom”. Onkelos translates it as “BeKadmin – Primordially”." which is Keser. It should be noted that the Alter Rebbe doesnt discuss any level above A.K. (Adam Kadmon) Before Tzimtzum (contraction that gives room for creation) the sefiros are completely unified with Hashem. Its a paradox. They exists but they dont. They are on the level of Yachid which is signular verses Echad which means many levels unite as one.

Comment: @mochinrechavim That's what I mean. You and I and some others here may be familiar with that, but I assure you that the majority here are not. Try to simplify and explain as much as possible.

Comment: @HodofHod I will try. We are talking about a pretty loft concept in general. I think anyone who doesn't understand the base of this discussion and is interested should read the book "Mystical Concepts in Chassidus" by R' Shochet. Published by Kehot

Comment: @mochinrechavim I agree that they are lofty concepts, thanks for trying to explain them for everyone. As far as the book goes I'd like to say FTR that the title is a bit of a misnomer, as most of the topics and ideas discussed therein are kabbalistic, albeit explained al pi chassidus.

Comment: @HodofHod Correct. The Rebbeim of Chabad are assuming that a Chasid understands the general stations of Seder Histalshelus which is purely Kabbalistic. I dont have a source but I do recall reading somewhere that the Previous Rebbe said that a chasid was not admitted in to hear a maamar if he did not understand Seder Histalshelus at a basic level. That book is a good crash course for the lofty themes that Chabad Chassidus will expound upon.

Comment: Why does Yesh Me'Ayin only start after God created these things? And are you saying that יהוה is not a name of God but a name of a certain thing he created as a tool?

Comment: @DoubleAA Names of God are tools for Hashem to interact with the created world. YHVH can not be compared to Elokim, or Shakai, or Aleph Hey Yud Hey which is the highest name. None of these are even a grain of sand on the beaches of earth compared to Ein Sof. So in short I am saying that Hashems names are tools and they do not reflect Hashems Essence because each one is limited in a certain way.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Do those names refer to God or do they refer to certain created and separate tools? (I'm thinking of names here as rigid designators.) If the latter, how does one understand verses like Braishis 17:1 or Shemos 6:3? (Also, do you have a response to my first point?)

Comment: @DoubleAA Before creation there was only Hashem. A supreme and simple being that is Yachid, singular. He created something out of nothing ie: creation which in the word he is Echad. Grammatically speaking Echad is a composite unity of many things. In this case it means G-d is one with these many things. This part of the discussion is a topic unto itself. Since there is 1 G-d why does he have some many names? The answer is that each name serves a purpose in a different situation and the sefirot do the same thing. Why does Shem Haveyeh call himself Shakai to Avra(ha)m? in 17:1?

Comment: "Grammatically speaking Echad is a composite unity of many things" ?!? I dont see how that follows from grammar or even logic for that matter, and frankly it sounds like outright Kefira. God doesn't have parts. One is one. There is no Oneness like God's oneness which is wholly One. Your sentence sounds perilously close to http://enwp.org/Saint_Patrick#St._Patrick_uses_shamrock_in_an_illustrative_parable The multiple names either refer to different tools, or all refer to the same single God (two words refering to the same thing is not odd; both "user1292" and "<name>" refer to you) Which is it?

Comment: In short: precisely what is the [referent](http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/referentterm.htm) of יהוה?

Comment: @DoubleAA The word Echad is one with the potential for something else to exist. Yachid is singular and unique. How else would we arrive at the word Achdus? We say Hashem Echad because we are declaring that Hashem is unique and singular even in the creation and is found everywhere as one. Please go review Rashi's commentary on the names of Hashem and even Rambam in Guide to the Perplexed (Vol. I, Chapter 61) agrees that Hashem manifests through dif. names

Comment: @user1212 I don't see how that answer's my question, nor do I follow your (?) etymological/grammatical (?) distinction.

Comment: Oh, and I'm still wondering why you only mention Yesh m'Ayin for the part of Creation that comes after the creation of the Sephirot, which would seem to also have been Yesh m'Ayin. ||| Now that I reread your post, I wonder: how do you know Tefillah isn't the primary form of worship of the "Sephirot-gods"? I don't know of anyone who worships them any other way. Additionally, even if you don't get killed for it doesn't mean that such a mistaken belief wouldn't make one into a _bonâ fide_ heretic.

Comment: @HodofHod Do you have any insights on the above (since the OP is not around)?

Comment: @DoubleAA Huh. When did Mochin leave? (Ah, that must have been that rep hit.) This concept is mentioned many times in Chassidus, I'm not sure I understand it well, let alone enough to explain it. A quick Google leads me to http://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/2741/jewish/The-Numerology-of-Redemption.htm Relevant part is paragraph beginning "Echad".

Answer (score 1):

Another way of saying the same thing as the answers above, but in a way that might be easier to understand for some lesser-initiated readers of this question:

Human beings cannot perceive G-d.  We can only perceive the ways that G-d's manifests his Will into human existence.

We call the Source of G-d's Will the "Ein Sof".  We can't describe G-d's essence in any positive terminology, for any description at all would itself be a false limitation.  Instead, we refer to G-d at "Without End".

The lowest sefirah is malchus - kingship.  That is the sefirah farthest away from Ein Sof - i.e. our physical world.

The other nine sefiros represent various manifestations of G-d's will.  The closer the sefirah is to the Source, the less that human beings are capable of experiencing that manifestation of G-d's Will.

This is one of the reasons why kabbalah was never studied by the general public until very recently in Jewish history.  Kabbalah uses descriptions like "closer to" and "farther from" G-d, even though G-d is not a physical entity, and therefore is never "close to" or "far from" anything.

Comment: It always seemed to me that the first chapter of Moreh Nevuchim applied just as much to Kabbalistic concepts as it does to "btzelem".  I am very far from being a mekubal, though, so I may be very wrong about that.