What is the response to the claim that the Zohar is a medieval document rather than an historical Jewish document?
I'm not trying to be offensive with this question. This isn't my claim.
I've recently read some criticism around the Zohar from academic sources which claim that the Zohar has no historical relationship to the Jewish people. The claim being made is that rather than being a secret teaching which had always existed alongside the original Torah, the Zohar was written during the medieval era and popularized around the same time period as other forms of mysticism which sprung up in that same period.
Instead of it being written by Shimon Bar Yochai, they instead claim it a work by a much later Sephardic Rabbi named Moses de León.
I love Zohar thought and I've always been a fan of it as being another layer on top of everything else that already exists in Judaism.
That being said, is there a response to this idea that the Zohar isn't original?
Does it ultimately matter in the long run if these ideas are simply complimentary to Judaism rather than changing foundational ideas within it?

On significance: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36988/why-does-the-authorship-of-the-zohar-matter . On authorship https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34302/did-r-moshe-de-leon-write-the-zohar (and linked question)

Everything was thought of at some point. What is the significance of it being thought of in 1300 CE rather than 100 CE? There's often an unstated implication that the gates were closed at some point. Why should that be?

@IsaacMoses Thank you for these links!

@Mike Shimon Bar Yochai's teachings, especially his notes from an ancient mesora, are far more valuable to most than those of Moses de Léon. It makes a huge difference. Also, who says the gates closed and why does that have to be the only issue?

@RabbiKaii I know that what you are saying is a conventional understanding, but it profoundly bothers me. It seems like we take away from the brilliance and innovation of the sages (often including Taanaim) when we say they didn't think of some of their ideas themselves. Rabbi Akiva probably did know Torah that Moses didn't and it is a problem that we put so much effort into covering that up. Rabbi Moses de Leon probably did create at least some ideas that did not exist before and that is to his credit. In Avot, we learn that we should cite the name of a source, not backdate it for prestige.

@Mike your otherwise great point doesn't apply here because we are not talking about ideas, but Kabbalah. That which is received. If the Zohar is Moshe De Léon's chiddush, then it is far less valuable than a Tannaic document. Just because it is less valuable does not mean it is worthless

Also, I personally agree that backdating seems a bit dodgy, especially if done for prestige. Which - if De Léon did really write the Zohar - would be true in this case and make it even less valuable
