# Sources in Rishonim on the Authenticity of the Zohar

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, rishonim, authorship, zohar

Are there any early contemporary discussions from the time of the revelation of the Zohar among recognized Rishonim about its authenticity?

I mention "among recognized Rishonim" because I am aware of Yitzchak d'min Acco discussing it, but was unfamiliar with his name outside the context of this discussion. I am looking for Rishonim of the caliber of the Ramban, Rashba, Ran, Ritva etc. who have commented on the subject.

I am also asking *specifically* for sources, and am not interested in a general discussion of the authenticity of the Zohar, hence this is not a dup of [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34269/did-rashbi-write-the-zohar) question

Comment: The Zohar was "published" towards the very end of R Moshe de Leon's life, which ended in 1305, as we know he died while dealing with initial controversy about the work. The Ramban dies in 1287 and the Rashba in 1310.

Comment: why should there be rishonim talking about it it was hidden away?

Comment: @ray the Zohar appeared at the end of the 13th century, hence towards the end of the period of the Rishonim. The Rishonim that flourished after it's revelation by R Moshe de Leon likely were exposed to the controversy surrounding it's revelation and most probably weighed in on one side or the other.

Comment: @DoubleAA the Ramban and Rashba were given merely as examples of the caliber of Rishonim I am looking for. The Meiri and Ran perhaps would have been more historically relevant examples

Comment: @Jewels I believe the Rashba actually did discuss it.  I will try to find it.

Comment: How about the Tashbetz? Does he count?

Comment: @Matt sounds good, do you have a source?

Comment: I had misread the question, sorry. I thought you were looking for rishonim who quoted the Zohar, not discuss its origin

Comment: Do you consider the Beis Yosef to be a rishon?

Comment: @Matt Or his son http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1380&pgnum=86

Answer (score 21):

Unfortunately, what you are requesting is not exactly possible.

The Zohar literature, including the *Zohar*, *Zohar Hadhash*, and the *Tiqunei HaZohar* - along with their respective books and sub-divisions - was published over the course of almost 300 years (approx. 1300-1587 CE) and straddles the periods of the late *Rishonim* and early *Aharonim*; the era of the former generally held to be during the 11th to 15th centuries, and the era of the later generally held to be from the 16th century until the present time.

Although there was much written on the subject of the Zohar and the authenticity of its content, only a minority of what is extant was authored in the narrow window between the publication of the Zohar literature and the end of the period of the *Rishonim*. Much of what exists in this genre was written in the period of the early *Aharonim* and remains very valuable.

What is available exists in two types: [1] independent works authored specifically on the subject of the authenticity of the Zohar literature, and [2] quotes from *Hazal* and major *Geonim* and *Rishonim* (such as *Rasag*, *Rashi*, *Tosafoth*, *Rambam*, et al) whose explicit statements in previous eras are directly contradicted by explicit statements made later by Zohar literature and its commentaries.

**Works in the period of the *Rishonim* written disputing the *Zohar* and its authenticity**:

- *Sefer Behinath HaDath* - Rav Eliyahu Del Medigo (15th Century CE)
- *Sefer HaYuhasin*, account of Rabbi Yishaq de-min Ako - Rav Avraham Zakuto (15th Century CE)

**Works in the period of the *Aharonim* written disputing the *Zohar* and its authenticity**:

- *Sefer Ari Nohem* - Rav Yehudah Aryeh DeModena (17th Century CE)
- *Mitpahath Sefarim* - Rav Ya`aqov Emden (18th Century CE)
- *Shu"T Hatham Sofer* (6:59), referring to the work of Rav Emden - Rav Mosheh Sofer (18th Century CE)
- *Vikuach Al Chochmas Hakabbalah* - Shada"l (19th Century CE)
- *Teshuvah Me-Ahavah* (1:14) - Rav Eli`ezer Fleckeles (19th Century CE)
- *Milhamoth HaShem* - Rav Yihye Qafih (19th Century CE)

These are by no means exhaustive lists, but they do comprise the majority of what is available.

Now, to list literature prior to the publication of the Zohar literature which deals with similar themes as the *Zohar*:

- *HaNivhar Emunoth wa-De`oth* - Rav Saadia Gaon (10th Century CE), This work is a comprehensive compendium of explanations not only of the position of Torah Judaism on hashqafic topics, but also includes the arguments of detractors and the basis for their being rejected. The interesting thing about this work is that it deals with almost every major theme of the later "Qabalah" embodied in the Zohar literature and rejects it as not being authentically Jewish. These topics include the idea of multiplicity or aspects as relates to the One Transcendent God, Reincarnation, and Emanation (*assiluth* אצילות) among others.
- *Moreh HaNavokhim* - Rav Mosheh ben Maimon (11th Century CE), a work also detailing the necessity of intellectual and rational approaches to understanding the texts of the Torah and Nevi'im, as well as explaining the meaning of many of the *misswoth* and the various reasons behind them. It also deals with concepts later embodied in the "Qabalah," such as "secret" mystical names of God and amulets, which are also roundly rejected.
- *Ma'amar Tehiyath HaMethim* - Rav Mosheh ben Maimon (11th Century CE), In the first section, the Rambam accounts for the misunderstanding of his own teachings regarding the resurrection from the dead by bringing an example of a gross misunderstanding of God's own words in the *Shema* (*Devarim* 6:4). He refers to the "belief of the dualists" who believe that the three mentions of the Divine Name in the *Shema* (i.e. *HaShem*, *Elohenu*, *HaShem*) are three separate forces/entities/modes of the Divine (*halilah wa-has*) which supposedly comprise a composite unity. The Rambam of course rejects this reading of the *Shema* in his words there. However, the *Zohar* (2:53b) later espouses just such an interpretation. This rather explicit text was ironically used by later Christian Hebraicists and the Catholic church in justifying the validity of their belief in a "Trinity" from "Jewish" teachings.
- *Rashi* and *Tosafoth* on *b.Meghillah* 9a (11th, 12th-13th Centuries CE), In an interesting passage about the request of King Ptolemy (*Talmai HaMelekh*) that the *hakhmei HaSanhedrin* write for him a copy of the Torah in Greek, the Gemara explains that several deliberate changes to the text were made in order to avoid polytheistic errors. Two of the notable changes were made to *B'reshith* 1:1 and 1:26; the former change being that instead of the text reading "*B'reshith bara Elohim*" they wrote "*Elohim bara b'reshith*," and the later being that in place of "*Na'aseh adham*" they wrote "*E'aseh adham*." In the first instance - due to syntax in the Greek language which often puts the most important noun in the sentence first and sorts out the meaning and parts of speech via case endings - the *hakhamim* did not want the Greeks to think that "*B'reshith*" was the name of one deity which created a second deity named "*Elohim*" (*halilah*) and that there are thus multiple powers in Heaven (*halilah wa-has*), so says *Rashi*. *Tosafoth* add to this by saying that "*B'reshith eino shem kelal ela ba-tehilah*" meaning that the term "*b'reshith*" is not a name at all, but is rather just the Torah's way of saying "In the beginning." The second change was made due to the presence of the plural form (i.e. "Let us make man"), lest again the Greeks think that the Torah promotes polytheism and that multiple gods created mankind (*halilah*), so says *Rashi*. However, the *Zohar* - in commenting on these very passages - adopts the mistaken and erroneous views which these changes were intended to negate. On *B'reshith* 1:1 the *Zohar* says that "*Reshith*" is the name of one of the *partzufim*/*sefiroth* and it creates another/emanates another *partzuf*/*sefirah* named "*Elohim*" which it can then inhabit. On *B'reshith* 1:26, the *Zohar* depicts two of the *partzufim* (faces/personalities which supposedly make up the Divine), "*Abba*" and "*Imma*," arguing whether or not they should make man - "*Abba*" is con while "*Imma*" is pro - and in the end "*Imma*" says that although mankind will sin against us "Let us make man" anyhow. The implications of these interpretations in light of the *Gemara* and its commentators are wide-reaching.

There are many more things which could be listed here, but much of it is already written in the works mentioned above.

I hope that this helps.

Kol tuv.

Comment: While certainly very well written, your article specifically avoids the points that I raised in my question, namely a)Rishonim and b) *recognized* Rishonim. And regarding the time span over which the mass of literature you mention was published, I specifically mentioned the *Zohar*, not the other works of Kabbala you mention like the Tikkunei Zohar, and by all accounts the Zohar itself certainly was publish by the early 1300's and hence there was plenty of time (150 years or so) for the Rishonim to comment about its authenticity

Comment: No, I answered your question in the first line and then continued to expound on what IS available to you. I answered your question fine. The fact is that all I had to write to answer it was that first line because there are NO "recognized" Rishonim who discuss the Zohar. And the Zohar Hadhash and the Tiqunei Zohar ARE considered parts of the Zohar. Another VERY important thing: the world was not as "small" in those times as you would like it to be. In other words, a book - though popular in one country - would not necessarily makes its way to the rest of the world so quickly...

Comment: ...consider how the Rambam, Rashi, and Rabenu Tam were contemporaries an yet they did not see each other's works in their lifetimes. This is because people WALKED everywhere and copied books BY HAND. So, 150 years is not much time at all for a single book to make its way to all of the areas where "recognized" Rishonim live (whatever "recognized" means). Your question is such that it cannot be answered; the Rishonim that I cited are, according to you, not "recognized" and the Rishonim you are looking for DON'T EXIST. The "Qabalah" that the Ramban and Raavadh knew were embodied in books like...

Comment: the Sefer HaBahir, Sefer Yessirah, Hekhaloth Literature, and perhaps even the Shi`ur Qomah, but not the Zohar. Murmurs and unattributed quotes here and there during the first few hundred years after Mosheh DeLeon published the Zohar is all that we have. What this tells us is that most did not even hear of it, while others MAY have heard of it or they may have only had access to the works on which the Zohar itself was based (i.e. prior works that DeLeon used to construct it). So again, I DID answer your question: "What you are requesting is not exactly possible." Kol tuv.

Comment: The question says "discuss the Zohar" not "quote the Zohar." And it even adds that it is looking for Rishonim who discuss the authenticity of the Zohar. Even if there seem to be quotes from it, they are not by name and the whole issue becomes rather circular since the Zohar also quotes directly from Rashi, Tosafoth, and Rambam, among others. Kol tuv.

Comment: Oh sorry I had misread the question. In that case, job well done. Of course, those groups that do believe that the Zohar's teachings were known to the very rishonim that you quote will tell you that you're only reading their works that were meant for the public. Secretly, however, they learned the opinions of the Zohar

Comment: @Maimonist Would you mind giving me a source for where the Rambam rejects Gematriyot in Moreh Nevuchim? TIA

Comment: @Maimonist I linked to your answer in this question http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/is-gematria-accepted-by-all  If you can provide an answer, that would be appreciated.

Comment: @user6618 - my apologies. I was almost certain that it was found there, but when trying to locate it again I was unsuccessful. I am still searching for where I read this originally, but in the meantime, I removed the statement from my answer. Kol tuv.

Comment: The Sefer Yuchsin part is not accurate. He discusses the controversy without a conclusion, yet he later quotes the Zohar. Likewise, R. Yaakov Emden is a big misrepresentation. He was only showing that the Sefer the way we have it is tampered with, but not that it is made-up. The same goes for the Chasam Sofer, who wrote many Zohar based Chidushim and Teshuvos.

Comment: @HaLeiVi There is nothing inaccurate here as you say. I have Rav Emden's sefer on my shelf and his wording is very explicit. I also have the Hath Sofer on my shelf and he likewise is clear in his statements. And many Zohar-based teshuvoth? That's funny because I also have a teshuvah from him that says explicitly that mixing kabbalah and halakhah is like creating a forbidden mixture that needs to be destroyed by burning. I understand that you are in love with the Zohar, but you need to check your facts.

Comment: Did you see his famous Tshuva on Nusach Hatfilla? True, he didn't mix Halacha and Kabbalah, because it is purely Kabbalah. What about his Chidushim? What about R. Emden's Siddur, annotated with Kabbalistic notes all throughout? I didn't come to prove a point -- I didn't address your whole answer. Just don't portray someone's opinion wrongly. But I will say that you went a bit off topic.

Comment: @HaLeiVi Being a Kabbalist is not the same as accepting the Zohar and rejecting the Zohar does not mean one is not a kabbalist. You are making equations that are not justified. I haven't misrepresented anything. Again, check your facts.

Comment: His annotations are based on the Arizal, who drew heavily from the Zohar (and had likewise held there are parts nit from the Zohar that made it in). He also quotes the Zohar. I called it a misrepresentation. The Sefer Yuchsin part was inaccurate.

Comment: Your argument from Rashi would apply as well to the Ramban and the Targum he quotes. Both are from before the Zohar came out. It's not much of an argument anyhow. The fact that we Darshen doesn't take away from the fact that there is a mistake to be made. Obviously, the Chachamim weren't about to explain the reason it is there.

Comment: @Maimonist samuel ibn seneh zarza in maqor hayyim parosho ki teisei writes against the authenticity of the zohar http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6145&st=&pgnum=239

Comment: @Maimonist http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/10584-meir-ben-simeon-of-narbonne  r meir ben shimon zl was a student of the kabbalist yishoq the blind https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_the_Blind . r meir ben shimon stated the bahir was a forgery and along with his father in law r mashullom ben moshe of beziers zl expelled the kabbalists from languedoc which is said to be the founding city of "kabbala"
 http://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/meshullam-ben-moses