# Hashem's Ontology and the Sefirot

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, number, theology, mysticism-kabbalah, sefirot-attributes

My question is, Hashem ontologically speaking, His Being, is a singular, yichud in all respects.

So does this conception stop at Ein Sof, or even before Ein Sof? And once the ohr proceeds forth from the Ein Sof down through the remaining sefirot, it is no longer considered Hashem's ontological Being, which is restricted to that which comes before Ein Sof?

My thinking is that since the Sefirot was created, it is not ontologically the same as Hashem.

Comment: G-d's oneness doesn't change or stop ever. But to give you a context, ask yourself if G-d"s oneness is changed by His names? Everyone recognizes and accepts that G-d has names like are found in the Torah of Moshe. The answer by all traditional Jewish teaching is that G-d transcends names, and even letters altogether. Names, letters, Sefirot, etc. are only for His creations.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8925/why-is-the-idea-of-sefirot-not-shituf?rq=1 and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8920/why-isnt-the-kabbalistic-doctrine-of-sefirot-considered-shittuf-if-the-christia?rq=1

Comment: A good way to understand Hashem's Oneness: _Hashem is *thoroughly* Himself_. The best mashal we have for this is when we invest ourselves into something. When we do something we love, like playing with our child, we completely identify with the love we feel and the games we play. "That's 100% who I am, right here", whereas when we do something we hate, we have to force ourselves like a robot to do it. Hashem being One, l'havdil is a bit like this, everything is Him. Thoroughly and completely and He's 100% identified with it that there's no difference at all.

Comment: This is the explanation given about the sefirot by the Kabbalistic giants (see Tzemach Tzeddek Derush Shalos Shitos in Ikarim). Don't assume Hashem only has the power of infinite, He also has the power of finite (Ramak). When Hashem made a finite world, the "finite" power He brought forth is 10 sefirot, but He is identified with them thoroughly. It's Him. B'EH this will not be misunderstood, it is very hard to put into words and I strongly recommend anyone reading this to go look up the sources and see it in the original before feeling like they've really understood it