# Self-association with God

Tags: soul, sefirot-attributes

I alway admired the Jews for having a belif system that their is only one God. But recently I got this message from a Christian that claimed that they associate themselves with God, by saying part of their souls is divine, see below:

"Also theos means divine it does not mean uncaused cause. Jews and Muslims do not believe in pne divine eternal entity they  believe that God and his word are together divine and eternal. Infact Jews go farther than us their God has 10 sefirot and the 10 are one and they teach that the higher part of the human soul is God. I do not understand how divine plurality is monotheistic for Jews and Muslims but divine plurality is polytheistic for Christians."

I have two question regarded this

1) do Jews believe 10=1, like Christians believe 3=1, that is in the literal sense i.e. 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1=1?

2)do Jews really believe that the higher part of the soul is God?

I do not what to know what Christians/Muslims believe compared to Jews, with respect to the above questions.

Comment: Regarding your second question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30469/whats-chelek-eloak-mimaal

Comment: @AsanRamzan Thanks for this question; I think it is fantastic. And yes, we, like Quakers (l'havdil) believe there is that of G-d in people, as indeed there is in everything on Earth and in Heaven

Comment: @SAH We do not believe that G-d exists in people. Contrary, we cannot know anything about G-d except for what G-d is not. We are created in the "image of G-d" yes, but Maimonides interprets image to mean intelligence and not a shape. For if this is so, does G-d have a shape?