# Are Jewish souls eternal?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, soul

Rabbi Kaplan in [Moreh Ohr 3:4 (p. 43)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=61862&st=&pgnum=48&hilite=), brings a quotation from the introduction of Shefa Tal:

> “The souls of the Jewish nation are a part of God, which is hinted to
> in Dev. 32:9 ‘כי חלק ה׳ עמו, For the Lord’s portion is his people’,
> meaning to say, an actual part of Him. Like a part of something that
> was split from another. The two parts are of equal and similar
> qualities.”

Leaving aside the notion that God has parts is philosophically impossible for Rambam since God is a unity, when Rabbi Kaplan quotes this source he seems to be endorsing it. For why would he bring the source if not to make some kind of point. The question is, if all Jewish souls are a part of God, and God is eternal, meaning uncreated, does this implies the souls of Jews are likewise eternal and not created? This would have to be the case if we are, in essence, a part of God because no part of God was created.

Comment: The soul was created the moment G-d "blew life into his nostrils" according to the Alter Rebbe in Tanya. Similary, Koheles writes what happens to the soul after death: the spirit returns to G‑d, who gave it.

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/1028875/jewish/Chapter-2.htm

Comment: @Shmuel why do you read that it was created then? Hashem blew it in - meaning it was already there. It's a "חלק אלוה ממעל ממש". The answer is emphatic yes - the Divine soul was never created, it is eternal. Contrast the human soul "נעשה אדם", formed from the creation, which itself was created. Turk, God is one with His people, we say it 3 times a day. Zohar says ישראל ואורייתא וקודשא בריך הוא חד הוא. This is an incredibly deep subject, and of course does not disagree with Rambam. It would be hard to answer your question in a simple manner. I might try to make an attempt as it would be valuable

Comment: Is it possible this quotation requires its larger context (both in ST and MO)?

Comment: @Shmuel Are you saying when the spirit returns to God, we live in God in the afterlife?

Comment: @RabbiKaii Thank you for your comment and I look forward to your answer.

Comment: @TurkHill It will certainly be a large project for me, I don't know how soon I can get around to it. May I recommend these two shiurim, as they will certainly be of immense use (yes, 4 hours total, this is a big big subject): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpe09_rvKCM and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPPqPT9CoIA

Comment: @TurkHill No, I'm not saying that and to be honest, I do not know if this can be explained so literally and simply. The Rambam did not explain things kabbalistic.

Comment: @RabbiKaii Thank you. I will wait for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The same question was asked to the author of the Shefa Tal. He wrote another [book](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22404&st=&pgnum=19) explaining that this quote was taken out of context by people who did not read the admonition in his first book to read it strictly in order. He explains that in Kabbalistic terminology "Hashem" is not always the term used to refer to G-d himself, but can refer to Sefiros which are creations of His. G-d himself is referred to as "Ein Sof" (limitless) which by definition can have no parts. So the souls are not part of G-d as we would say it in English, but part of "Hashem".

[This is based on my limited understanding and quick perusal of his work. I linked to the entire work so you can read more if you'd like.]

This distinction answers a lot of the other objections people have to Kabbalistic thought.

Comment: Derech Hashem, 1:1:5 אך האדון ית״ש איננו בעל כחות שונים אעפ״י שבאמת יש בו ענינים שבנו הם שונים כי הרי הוא רוצה והוא חכם והוא יכול והוא שלם בכל שלימות אמנם אמתת מציאותו הוא ענין א׳‎ שכולל באמתתו וגדרו (פי׳‎ אמתת ענינו כי אין שייך גדר בו ית׳‎ אלא על צד היתר לשון) כל מה שהוא שלימות ונמצא שיש בו כל השלימיות, this is how the Ramchal deals with it.

Comment: @RabbiKaii That is not dealing with it. That perek of Ramchal is based on Shaar Hayichud of Chovos Halevavos, which supports OP's question. See his Maamar Hachochmah instead.

Comment: I don't follow how this is not dealing with it, sorry. Maybe we are talking about a different "it"?

Comment: @RabbiKaii That perek of Ramchal supports OP's question.

Comment: I agree with you, so I'm not sure why it sounds like you are _disagreeing_ with me?

Comment: @RabbiKaii It sounded to me like you quoted Ramchal to answer the question, but your quotation makes the question stronger.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. No, it was a response to your answer - this is how Ramchal deals with the "parts" of Hashem, which I believe is different (or sounds different, who are we to get into the minds of these great tzaddikim) to the answer you gave.

Comment: I don't think that is enough to answer OP's question. Also that quote of Ramchal is pretty standard. If you want my take on it, you can find it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vKSuv3bpiho_cuc1rkU3xCmX1AYxRyMZ/view?usp=share_link or here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DR1sTFJFz_aUpk7T0bbfyLt3de0ZQQJH/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Agreed it's not enough to answer the question, I'd like to make an attempt at a fuller answer at some point. Thanks for providing your shiurim, I'll try to listen to them.

Comment: I skipped to the part where you discuss this. Very interesting take. I'll try to incorporate it into my answer if I ever get around to it.

Comment: Thanks for listening. And the really full answer is the book I linked to; in which the author of Shefa Tal himself addresses the question head on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your description of how souls are not a part of God but a part of Hashem is interesting.

Comment: I don't claim to fully understand it, but  that is what the author says.

Comment: Upvoted your answer but I think you meant to say "browse" etc rather than "peruse" the latter means to read something deep and through and thoroughly (per- = through) ! A commonly misused word alas

Comment: @NissimNanach I was not aware of that meaning. Merriam Webster says both are true: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peruse

Comment: peruse To read or examine, esp. with great care [ME *perusen*, to use up : Lat. *per-* (intensive) + ME *usen*, to use]

Comment: Above is the one and only def in American Heritage Dictionary, Second College Edition 1976, I typed it out straight from my print tome

Comment: I'm not interested in debating the point. Personally I have only seen it used as skim

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that there is no chiddush (novelty) in something being eternal. Everything that Hashem does should, by default, be eternal. The bigger chiddush is how can there be something not eternal? That's [tzimtzum](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/361884/jewish/Tzimtzum.htm), and it is a paradox.

Therefore, back to the subject of eternal. There is eternal, and there is Eternal. When it comes to Hashem, the Eternal One, He is alone, His greatness is inexpressible.

Yet we also say that Nishmat Yisrael is eternal. According to Midrash Rabbah, Bereishit 8:7, Hashem consulted the souls of the righteous before creation. Who are they? According to Yishayahu 60:21, this is referring to all of Israel. As Rashi famously [states](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.1.1.2), בִשְׁבִיל יִשְׂרָאֵל, for the sake of Israel.

As we said, the notion of limitation and finitude exist only because of the tzimtzum, where there is a concept of time. In that framework, we discuss the Godly souls that were created "before" time<sup>1</sup>, before tzimtzum. **They are creations by Hashem, yet they are eternal because they exist beyond time.**

There is, however, one more important point to bring at this stage, which is what you have brought in your question, i.e. חלק אלוה ממעל ממש<sup>2</sup>. As one studies these topics, one notices that this idea seems to be in a category of its own. The concept of two souls, human and Godly, has a third layer, and that is this "literal, actual portion of God". So, what is it?

We say that Hashem, the Eternal One, may He be blessed, didn't change when He created the world<sup>3,4</sup>, and that He is not a Creator in Essence<sup>4</sup> (i.e. creating is out of character for Him).

---

<sub>You have raised the point that this answer shouldn't contradict the Rambam's doctrine of apophasis, as well as the general Torah principle that Hashem has no parts. Indeed it does not pose a contradiction to these truths. Note that the Rambam discusses Hashem's will without reserve<sup>5</sup> - Hashem being wilful is still a mashal in that we *can't* comprehend how profound and infinite His will is, nor how He can be One with His will without parts<sup>6</sup>, so, while we look at how our tzaddikim took this true, accurate mashal<sup>7</sup> and explained its details, we **must** keep that in mind. Proceeding from here:</sub>

---

What someone wants, and what they enjoy, tell you more about someone than any other expression or facet of their being. This is indeed a Kabbalistic idea<sup>8</sup>, but said in these terms I think many can relate. It may be impossible to truly get to know someone, because we aren't able to see each others' inner worlds, yet if you find out what I like, and what I want, you'll know me very well. So we can say that even though "no thought can apprehend Him"<sup>9</sup>, we can get to know Him by finding out what He desires.

We have everything we need now to answer your question:

**Hashem, the Eternal One, Himself chooses and desires Nishmat Yisrael**. This Ratzon and Ta'avah<sup>10</sup> Hashem has<sup>11</sup>, rises from what has always been - even "before" there was a people - truly unchanged; Eternal and One with His Essence in a way that is ineffable and indescribable. **This is the חלק אלוה ממעל ממש. I.e. it's Him, may He be blessed.**

> אילו ידעתיו הייתיו
> <sub>(Yedayah Ben Abraham Hapenini)</sub>

As the Shefa Tal writes in your quote, we have in our truth a corresponding, super-rational authentic Godly desire for Him in our Godly soul, with which we choose Him with a truly free will, that is one with our essence, l'havdil. I *highly recommend* [this short, jargon-free, crystal clear shiur](https://youtu.be/zWdkCVrMEbc) for a great introduction to this idea. There are hints at a deeper oneness in this, free of any separation or parts.

---

<sup>**Disclaimer**: the reader is urged to consider this a partial, imperfect answer and *not* conclude they now understand this subject after reading. Further study is urged.</sup>

<sup>The subject is very extensive and it has been very hard to choose which concepts to bring and which to leave out for brevity. I welcome questions. Perhaps, once every decade or so, I will come and update this answer as my own learning and understanding mature. As with everything on this site, ask your LOR, and research the provided sources for yourself. Any mistakes made here are my own, may Hashem forgive.</sup>

<sup>I hope we all are able to speedily fulfil the verse דַּע֩ אֶת־אֱלֹהֵ֨י אָבִ֜יךָ (Divrei Hayamim 1:28:9) so that we can be עׇבְדֵ֗הוּ בְּלֵ֤ב שָׁלֵם֙ וּבְנֶ֣פֶשׁ חֲפֵצָ֔ה - i.e. fulfil His desire that we have just discussed, for His sake.</sup>

---

<sup>1 - See Tanya Chapter 2 [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Tanya%2C_Part_I%3B_Likkutei_Amarim.2.2?vhe=Kehot_Publication_Society)

2 - Ibid [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Tanya%2C_Part_I%3B_Likkutei_Amarim.2.1?vhe=Kehot_Publication_Society)

3 - Adon Olam; [Gevurot Hashem Hakdama 2](https://www.sefaria.org/Gevurot_Hashem%2C_Second_Introduction_to_Gevurot_Hashem), Maharal; many other places

4 - Torah Or, Megilat Ester 99B, Alter Rebbe; Zohar

5 - for example [in Moreh Nevuchim](https://www.sefaria.org/Guide_for_the_Perplexed%2C_Part_1.46.10):
ואמנם פעולותיו – בעצמו לא בכלי. והכוחות באין ספק מכלל הכלים; אם כן
אינו בעל כח – כלומר: שיהיה בו ענין זולת עצמו בו יעשה או ידע **או ירצה** "His actions are accomplished by His Essence, not by any organ, and as
undoubtedly physical forces are connected with the organs, He does not
posses any such forces, that is to say, He has, besides His Essence,
nothing that could be the cause of His action, His knowledge, or **His
will**".

6 - Hashem's will, His Ratzon, and He Himself are one, and He doesn't require or have a body, or a "faculty" for it, but surely He is wilful. As the Ramchal [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Derekh_HaShem%2C_Part_One%2C_On_the_Creator.5):  אך האדון ית״ש איננו בעל כחות שונים אעפ״י שבאמת יש בו ענינים שבנו הם
שונים **כי הרי הוא רוצה** והוא חכם והוא יכול והוא שלם בכל שלימות "However the Master, may His name be blessed, does not have different
capabilities, even though He actually has properties that are
differing within us. **For surely He is willful** and is wise and is
powerful and He is perfect in every perfection..."

7 - The Mashal and the Nimshal are one, 'Hashem Hu HaElokim'. See [Ma'amar Veyadata](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/85424/jewish/Maamar-VeYadaata.htm)

8 - The highest mashal of all is the sefira of Keter (Crown; Ratzon/Ta'anug, will/delight). It is the closest to the Truth of the Nimshal (tenor), so we can say that Hashem's expressed ratzon and inner ta'anug are the closest (in perhaps quality if not quantity) we can get to know Him, His Essence, in our language and thinking.

9 - Tikkunei Zohar, Introduction 17a; Psalms 145:3

10 - [Tanya Chapter 36](https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/976273/jewish/Chapter-36.htm); [Bamidbar Rabbah 13:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Bamidbar_Rabbah.13.6), [Midrash Tanchuma Bechukotai 3:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Bechukotai.3.1), [Midrash Tanchuma Nasso 16:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Nasso.16.1)

11 - In Kabbalistic language, this is for the Yechida of the Nefesh Elokit of Yisrael, the Kallah for Him; the Chatan etc.</sup>

Comment: Would it be correct to summarize as follows? When it says that the souls of the Jewish nation ("Nishmat Yisrael") are a חלק אלוה ממעל ממש, it really means that in our closest approximation (in mashal terms of course) to understanding His Essence, Hashem's Ratzon is to choose and want the Nishmat Yisroel. And it is in that sense that the Nishmat Yisroel are a חלק אלוה ממעל ממש, because they are the object of the most essential aspect of G-d (His Ratzon), according to our understanding.

Comment: @user9806 Yes! Very good. The singular "Nishmat" is because we are all one soul - the Yechida of Am Yisrael

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree that God is Eternal and we are eternal (that is outside of time). There is a debate in Rambam about whether God has a will. Some argue that for Rambam God has no conscious will or no will at all. But, I suppose we will never know if God has a will or not.

Comment: @TurkHill you welcome and ty. I would agree, Hashem doesn't "have" a "will". I would disagree with the basic understanding of "He has no will at all", which might imply a lifeless statue ch'v, nobody holds this. On the contrary, Hashem is One, which "will" is a mashal for. We can't comprehend Oneness, but as with any comparator, the nimshal is more, not less. In this case, Oneness is far more alive than we can comprehend, and "will" seems small and insignificant in comparison. I assume you and the people you quoted would agree, even if we all admit this is impossible to truly grasp :)

Comment: Hi Rabbi. I understand that from the person who explained this Rambam to me, for Rambam, in his view, God has no conscious will. He means to say that God has no will and that this is Rambam's view. There is some precedence for it. Rambam states that God does not change and a will is a change in God. But God is beyond human comprehension so we just don't know. We do know that only God is a source of absolute truth.

Comment: I'm glad you liked the question and I liked your answer. We can have a chat. I like chats. Maimonides tells us that we know nothing about God. If we study the laws of nature, we will learn about what God created. This is all we know.

Comment: @TurkHill I deleted my comment to avoid extended discussion. I'm unaware of where Rambam says it like that so I'm not sure what use I'll be. I am still working my way through MN slowly :) I'll start a chat at some point bli neder. Shalom

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142738/discussion-between-turk-hill-and-rabbi-kaii).

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to the question posed in your title is, yes.

The real question is how does this relate to the posuk in the Torah which the author of Shefa Tal references? And to truly understand that, it helps to look at the complete sentence quoted in context with the one which precedes it, namely Devarim 32:8-9 which says:

> בְּהַנְחֵ֤ל עֶלְיוֹן֙ גּוֹיִ֔ם בְּהַפְרִיד֖וֹ בְּנֵ֣י אָדָ֑ם יַצֵּב֙ גְּבֻלֹ֣ת עַמִּ֔ים לְמִסְפַּ֖ר בְּנֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵֽל׃
> כִּ֛י חֵ֥לֶק יְהֹוָ֖ה עַמּ֑וֹ יַעֲקֹ֖ב חֶ֥בֶל נַחֲלָתֽוֹ׃

When the Most High gave nations **their inheritance** while dividing humanity,**[God] fixed the boundaries** of peoples **according to the number** *(numerical value, meaning gematria)* **of Israel**. Because His nation (meaning Israel) is a division, or *distribution* of (G-d's name) יהוה, **Yaacov**, (*another name for* **Israel**) (*like a*) *woven cord* (a woven cord is comprised of three threads) or rope **is His inheritance**.

So keeping in mind that G-d and His name are one, like Rambam poskins in [Mishneh Torah Hilchot Teshuvah 5:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Repentance.5.5?vhe=Torat_Emet_363&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) which says:

> הוּא יִתְעַלֶּה שְׁמוֹ וְדַעְתּוֹ אֶחָד

If G-d's name (יהוה) is examined:

י׳ פעמים ה׳ פעמים ו׳ meaning 10 times 5 times 6 results in 300 or ש׳

י׳ פעמים (ה׳ עם ו׳ (עם המלוי דה״ה אחרונה או באופן אחר ה׳ משם הראשון וה׳ משם זה)

meaning 10 times (5 plus 6 plus (10, meaning 5 plus 5) for a total of 10 times 21) equals 210 or י״ר.

יהוה עם אותיות וכולל meaning 26 plus 4 plus 1 equals 31 or א״ל.

And together, these three distributions of G-d's name, woven together form Israel (ישראל). That quite literally חֵ֥לֶק יְהֹוָ֖ה עַמּ֑וֹ.

Comment: Thank you for your asnwer.