# Can a Ben-Noach practice another religion?

Tags: gentiles, noachide-laws

Could a Ben-Noach actively practice a religion other than Judaism as long as it isn't considered avoda zara? Suppose, for example, he was born Muslim. Could he continue to actively follow Islam and still be considered to be following the Noachide laws?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89/3

Comment: Dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11283

Comment: nope, not if they want to keep the 7 mitzvos bnei noach

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I do not mean to suggest that they cannot have a portion in the world to come, if they do keep the 7 mitzvos, they are nevertheless not permitted to observe another religion:

> The general principle governing these matters is: They are not to be allowed to originate a new religion or create mitzvot for themselves based on their own decisions. They may either become righteous converts and accept all the mitzvot or retain their statutes without adding or detracting from them.
>   [Rambam, Mishneh Torah, Hilchos Melachim 10:9](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188355/jewish/Chapter-10.htm/)

Comment: Not creating a new religion does not mean they are not allowed to follow an existing religion

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, that is clearly not a distinction justified in the Rambam, he makes it clear that their option is be a ben noach or convert

Comment: Perhaps the down-voter could elaborate on what they found incorrect about my presentation of the sources or whether they just do not like the questions answer.

Comment: Rambam also says they may not make a sabbath or festival for themselves

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman yes it does because all other religions are created by peope

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a Ben Noach is allowed to practice another religion as long as it doesn't break any of the 7 Noahide laws.

As for your example, according to the Rambam Muslims have no problem with their belief system (obviously there are other issues that the Rambam does have - but that is not within the context of this discussion).

Comment: Also note that many radical Muslims today believe that Jews are evil and want to kill us, so there's that...

Comment: @SethJ I don't see the relevance. pzkd, a source is always appreciated.

Comment: @DoubleAA  My point is that the RaMBa"M may object to that, as it is not in line with the 7 Mitzvoth.

Comment: @SethJ but one can easily be a fully practicing Muslim who is accepted as such by other Muslims without wanting to kill Jews. So it seems as though the practice of Islam itself would be OK. Of course, it is obviously possible to be a practicing member of a non-avoda-zara religion and still not follow the other mitzvot b'nei noach.

Comment: @Daniel, of course.

Comment: @SethJ RaMBaM's objections and agreements with the Islamic angle for a Ben Noahh has to do with the basic tenets of their religion  (ie the things that all sects would agree on) Not potential reactionary theology. pzkd said it best RaMBaM says that muslims are monotheist and can merit life in the world to come but thats not to say that every thing in their theology is remotely correct.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. @SethJ Hence why I don't see the relevance.

Comment: This is factually incorrect

Comment: What about liberal christian like me? I don't even know if Jesus is God or not (nor did he ever claim that directly). I think he's a pretty good rabbi and the most popular one by far and may have correct opinions.

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Tzvi Freeman of Chabad.org has suggested that Noahides should draw on aspects of the traditional faith in which they were raised. For example, see here:

http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/857823/jewish/Should-I-Convert-to-Judaism.htm

Under this line of thinking, a Noahide with Muslim roots should not practice Islam exactly, but a Noahidism with Islamic influences.

For example, perhaps post-Muslim Noahides will one day publish a volume with selections from the Koran, hadiths, etc., while leaving out anything that contradicts Judaism (such as the Muslim belief that the Jews edited the Torah to take out prophecies of the prophet Mohamed) or speaks negatively about Jews.

Comment: So after getting in touch with their own roots and then forming a society of noahides from many different religious backrounds they will end up being part of the Freemasonry:)