# Halachic status of Sikhism as Avoda Zara

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, noachide-laws

Are there any sources that explicitly discuss the halachic status of Sikhism regarding to what extent it follows the Noahide laws, and if it is considered avoda zara or shittuf?

Comment: See the wikipedia page. It seems that they are a purely monotheistic religion.

Comment: @Ephraim Wikipedia also [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christianity) that Christianity is a monotheistic religion, but that does not mean that it is not avoda zara according to halacha.

Comment: @Malper, the Sikhs have no doctrine like the trinity. And I see no doctrine, or aspects thereof that are manifestly problematic.

Comment: Somewhat (tangentially) related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18623/can-a-ben-noach-practice-another-religion

Answer (score 5):

From what I understand "avoda zara" or "shittuf" means, our religion, Sikhism, is neither. It's a monotheistic religion where we believe in the existence of one Omni-Present God.

He is above all. He is not confined in any idol or temple. He created us. We respect Him for what He has given us. (That's why we are not supposed to trim body or facial hair, or perform circumcision.)

Regarding Noahide laws, I am not able to understand them clearly. I apologize. I will do some more research and get back on that later.

Comment: Hello G.D. Singh. Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Just so you know, the reason this answer has been downvoted is because it does not answer the question. As is mentioned in the comments, Christianity considers itself to be monotheistic, but we consider it to be shittuf. The question asks for **sources** that discuss the **halachic** status of Sikhism. Not for personal opinion based on random internet people's interpretation of halacha.

Comment: I think you give a good answer regarding what Sikhism is and there is a good chance that you are correct (and that is "pure monotheism" similar to Judaism and Islam), but that not exactly what was asked.  Thank you for your input anyway since it was still informative.

Comment: As i quoted i was not able to understand the words used in the question clearly, as they are new and complex to me. But on my behalf i think i have answered the question partially correct as our religion is not "abodah zara". It's a monotheistic religion. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotheistic#Sikhism Coming to downgrading the answer, there was not need for it. My answer was just incomplete, just like other answers mentioned here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12229/avodah-zarah-in-other-religions These answers mostly do not cite any references too.

Comment: @G.D.Singh Why do monotheistic religion and Avoda Zara have to do with each other? You can worship only one God, but if it's the wrong God, that doesn't really help much, does it? I appreciate your interest in helping, but without a basic understanding of Jewish law, you won't be able to contribute much to a discussion thereof.

Comment: I disagree, @doubleaa. Not entirely, but on the point that this isn't a valuable contribution. It can be improved upon, certainly, but I think it's a useful starting point for the Halachic discussion.

Comment: This answer is downvoted, I'm sure, because of the fact that, although informative, it's incomplete (at best). The question specifically asks for sources explicitly discussing the Halachic status of Sikhism. Despite its usefulness in the discussion (which I believe it has, as I stated above), there's a good case to be made for deletion as "not an answer".

Comment: Avodah Zarah means that you believe in an intermediary between you and G-d. So, if that is what Sikhism believes in, they are Avodah Zarah.

Comment: Also, some groups in Christianity use Jesus as an intermediary, so they are Avodah Zarah.

Comment: @G.D.Singh search the Internet for the 7 laws of Noah

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any halachic literature on the subject, but I've never seen any reason to treat it as Avoda Zara. Sikhism has some qualms with some of the *practices* of Islam (e.g. circumcision) but generally stays quite close to its overall theology.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe Sikhism contains elements of either avodah zarah or problematic Shituf.

Sikhism is a strict monotheism (Ek Onkar - One God) based on the teachings of the 11 Gurus (10 human teachers, one textual, the Guru Grath Sahib).  It was started around 1500 CE by Guru Nanak in the Punjab part of India.

For baptized (ordained/confirmed) Sikhs (male or female), strict vows are undertaken - lesser vows by the lay membership.  These include 
-Rise in the anrit vela (21/2 hrs before sunrise) and recite morning prayers, meditations, yoga and others practices
-Recite 2 other prayers throughout the day
-Recite the evening prayer around sunset
-Recite the night prayer before sleep
-Refrain from intoxicants and stimulants
-Treat all people with respect and courtesy and protect all human rights
-Earn an honest living
-Share with those in need

For many “baptized” (amritdhari) Sikhs they have additional commitments: 
-Refrain from all meats, fish, etc.
-Keep all hair  - kesh and wear the dastar (turban)
-Carry kirpan (ceremonial blade), at least symbolically
-Wear kachera (modest undershorts)
-Use a kanda (wooden comb)
-Wear the kara (steel bangle)

Put very simply, these are the do's and don'ts of Sikhism:
Do:
 -Respect the equal rights of all regardless of rank, gender, caste,
   class, color, or creed. 
 -Share with others, especially those in need.
 -Perform altruistic service for humanity. 
 -Earn income by honest employment. 
 -Come to the aid of the defenseless. 
 -Keep all hair intact and unaltered. 
 -Meditate and read or recite daily prayers.
 -Worship and recognize one divine light manifest in all. 
 -Regard any other than one’s spouse as brothers or sisters. 
 -Become initiated as Khalsa and wear the five articles of faith. 
 -Follow ideals of the ten gurus, accepting the perpetual guidance of Sikhism's scripture the Guru Granth.

Eleven Sikhism Don'ts
    The goal of Sikhism is to subdue and overcome the effects of ego which foster duality and work to keep one from realizing enlightenment and union with the divine. These eleven Sikhism don’ts outline means of avoiding falling into the trap of egocentric living.
Don't:
 -Worship idols.
 -Deify any human being.
 -Pray to demigods or deities.
 -Observe caste or gender inequality.
 -Give credence to auspicious dates, horoscopes, or astrology.
 -Be involved with illegal activities or dishonorable associates.
 -Cut or otherwise alter the hair of the head, face, or body.
 -Engage in premarital or extramarital intimacies.
 -Eat the meat of sacrificial animals.
 -Practice superstitious rituals.
 -Smoke or use intoxicants.

My knowledge of Sikhism is from being a professor of World Religions (and knowing adherents of Sikhi) and my knowledge regarding avoda zara and halacha is from being a rabbi.  Brachot.

Comment: May be that some informations in your post are not needed for the proof that Sikhism isn't AZ. or Shituf.