# Is Sikhism Compatible with the 7 Laws of Noah

Tags: halacha, marriage, shidduchim-dating, intermarriage

I am an observant Noahide looking to get married.  Could you please let me know if Sikhism is compatible with the 7 Laws of Noah?

Is there a rabbi you could refer me to for discussing this further?

Warm regards,

DR

Comment: I already voted to close as a request for a practical ruling, but it seems that the to degree this question could be reworked to fit the site, it has already been asked here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33734/halachic-status-of-sikhism-as-avoda-zara so it is a duplicate.

Comment: Except for potential practical issues, to my knowledge, intermarriage is not technically forbidden to Noachides.

Comment: (...unless it counts as *abizrayhu*?)

Comment: Anyway, this is probably closureworthy as a "question that requires of its answerers knowledge of a religion besides Judaism" (IIRC the closure reason).

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33734/halachic-status-of-sikhism-as-avoda-zara