# Does belief in the abrogation of the Torah by the NT disqualify a Ben Noah?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, christianity, noachide-laws

The Rambam in Hilchos Melachim 8:10-11 (see also Likkutei Sichos [vol. 26 p. 132](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16021&st=&pgnum=143&hilite=)) rules it is a prerequisite of the 7 Noahide Laws that Gentiles bide by them because it says so in “the Torah of **Moses**".

> "Anyone who accepts upon himself and carefully observes the Seven Commandments is of the Righteous of the Nations of the World and has a portion in the World to Come. This is as long as he accepts and performs them because (he truly believes that) it was the Holy One, Blessed Be He, Who commanded them in the Torah, and that it was through Moses our Teacher that we were informed that the Sons of Noah had already been commanded to observe them. But if he observes them because he convinced himself logically, then he is not considered a Resident Convert and is not of the Righteous of the Nations of the World, but merely one of their wise."

Accordingly, does the Christian doctrine of the [abrogation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abrogation_of_Old_Covenant_laws) of the “Old Testament” by the “New Testament” of **Yoshke**, disqualify adherents of Christianity as Pious Amongst the Nations.

(Provided they don’t believe in the trinity nor consider Yoshke an incarnation of G-d ח״ו, otherwise they are oivdei avodah zarah mamash not shituf as per [psak](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49820&st=&pgnum=356) of HaRav Moshe Sternbuch ראב״ד of the Edah HaChareidis)

Comment: @TamirEvan [Nontrinitarian](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontrinitarianism) churches. I started going through a couple but I see various have serious issues anyways.

Comment: @TamirEvan [Survey - A Majority Of Americans Think Jesus Is A Great Teacher Yet Reject His Claims To Be G-d](https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/a-majority-of-americans-think-jesus-is-a-great-teacher-yet-reject-his-claims-to-be-god-301119281.html)

Comment: I believe your headline asks a different question than your post. There are gentiles that "believe" in the NT but deny the abrogation of the Torah: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-covenant_theology Perhaps consider editing the title to "Does belief in the abrogation of the Torah by the NT disqualify a Ben Noah?"

Comment: Thanks for noting that, never heard of those before, I’ll change it.

Comment: @Deuteronomy in the wikipedia article you sent though it says “ Dual-covenant theology is unique in holding that the Mosaic covenant remains valid for Jews while the *”New Covenant only applies to non-Jews or gentiles.”*  it may still be a problem then because the 7 mitzvos are for Gentiles.

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11283/can-a-noachide-continue-to-believe-in-religious-tenets-that-are-against-the-tora

Comment: @YehoshuaLevy I'm not an expert on Christian theology, but my understanding is that most Christian systems do not affirm a full abrogation of the Torah. Many (most?) of their theologians maintain that moral laws have not been abrogated but that ceremonial and civil laws have. I think you would need to know the details of the specific sect to make a determination here.

Comment: @Deuteronomy agreed that’s exactly what I wrote in the answer. “if they believe in the Revelation at Sinai intrinsically and that Yoshke only came and annulled commandments he disagreed with, then Moshe’s commandments remain unaltered.”

Answer (score 1):

Yes. See the Rambam you bring in the question.

Comment: I understand, but it’s interesting I have never seen Poskim address it. Perhaps there’s a reason?

Comment: It may depend on the following: Do they believe in Sinai only through Yoshke ימש"ו or maybe they do believe because of Moshe and it is only the “laws” that say were renewed.

Comment: In the latter they do believe Moshe commanded them, so if they believe Yoshke only *annulled* laws he disagreed with, then the 7 Mitzvos remain through Moshe. But if yoshke came and *renewed* the Torah ח״ו then they would be disqualified as Pious Gentiles.

Comment: How many Poskim discuss the qualifications for Bnei Noach after the Rambam?