# Is Listening to Christian music a sin or just not something a jew would normally do?

Tags: music, christianity, performance-entertainment

Is listening to a Christian song such as [Al Shadi](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuXB1a3NBCw) (which is partly in Hebrew) **a sin**, or is it just not something a Jew would listen to but not strictly sinful?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mi Yodeya.  I hope you enjoy the site, and I look forward to seeing you around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this answer on a question about performing such music](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12122/472), Igrot Moshe writes ([Yoreh De'ah 2:56](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&pgnum=74)) that it is asur (forbidden) to listen to music that has avodah zara/Christian intent in it.  Assessing intent is not always clear-cut and other sources may be more lenient in ambiguous cases, but both the lyrics and the images in the video you linked leave no doubt about *that* song, which subverts Jewish themes to promote Christianity.  (I'm basing that on paging through the subtitles; audio was off.)