# where if anywhere, does rashi refer to christianity as idolatry?

Tags: avodah-zarah, rashi, christianity

I remember  hearing that rashi does not consider christianity idolatry.

In researching it on google

I have read [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yaAWEzVfL6AC&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=rashi+christianity+idolatry&source=bl&ots=XxF6mFpbow&sig=75rSp40FzfNwvVxr0O5CHtp7-5k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipr5zW9vHKAhXHtxoKHYaSDZkQ6AEIMTAD#v=onepage&q=rashi%20christianity%20idolatry&f=false)

Isaac On Jewish and Christian Altars:Polemic and Exegesis in Rashi and the ...
By Devorah Schoenfeld

that book says "Rashi is clear that he considers Christians to be idolators"

However, the sources it quotes don't seem to  me to show that.

It quotes him in his commentary on Talmud Sotah 49b saying,  "Jesus and his followers who are called sectarians[minim]"

But Minim AFAIK just means heretics, which is not necessarily idolators, and not even forbidden in the noahide laws.

And the book quotes him as saying "Gentiles in our time are not experts in idolatry".   So the book is suggesting that since it says they're not experts in it, it suggests or implies that they are into it, just not into it big time.

So what was Rashi's view on whether Christianity is idolatry, and to what extent do we even know what his view was?

Comment: I took a look at Sotah 49b and can't find what you are quoting. I can't even find it on 47a.

Comment: The [Rashbam in Rashi's name](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_25134_26.pdf) says that in those days Christians shouldn't be considered idolators.

Comment: @Cauthon if you can quote that RASHBAM  With the relevant part in English, then i'll accept that as an answer.   Also, any idea why he says "in those days" and what he means by that? Thanks

Comment: @Cauthon also, do you think that RASHBAM in rashi's name, contradicts  Rashi on AZ 6a, as quoted by DoubleAA?

Comment: Rashi in Avoda Zara doesn't state his opinion as I understand, only explains the *gemara*. The Rashbam tells us explicitly that Rashi thought that they were not considered idolators (in Rashi's time), and the *Beit Yosef* explains that this is because they didn't really know what they were doing, but simply following in their fathers' footsteps. A short article about this [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25134&st=&pgnum=25).

Comment: @Cauthon i suppose rashi accepts the  or that gemara? how is rashi's interpretation of the gemara not his opinion?  it it common that he gives his  interpretation of a gemara but doesnt accept it?

Comment: related-  http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89/is-christianity-avodah-zara

Comment: @barlop many times you can see contradictions in Rashi (e.g. his commentary on the Bible vs his commentary on the Talmud, on the same word/subject), for several reasons (e.g. in one place he explains something in a halachic context, and in another he explains it in a midrashic context, etc.). Also, the gemara might have a rule about something, and later sages will say the rule doesn't apply in their specific case/time/etc. which is different than the gemara's. So it's not always about accepting the gemara per se, which most do, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Rashi on AZ 6a](http://daten.digitale-sammlungen.de/bsb00039616/image_1) says that the prohibition of doing business with idolaters close to their holidays (lest they offer thanks to their god(s)) applies to Christians. (The Talmud says the cited prohibition applies to נוצרי which Rashi defines as 'those who follow the mistake of Jesus who commanded them to make a holiday on Sunday.)

Note the word "Minim" has historically sometimes had particularly Christian implications (see [here](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/10846-min)).

Comment: So, can you interpret Rashi opposing Jewish merchants selling toys to Christians for Christmas?

Comment: @BruceJames Potentially. The applicability of that prohibition nowadays is a different question than the OP's.

Comment: What's your view on what Couthan says  i.e. that RASHBAM in Rashi's name says that christians in those days should not be considered idolators? http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_25134_26.pdf

Comment: This may be about Christianity in general, but not about Christians in Rashi's days, as discussed [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25134&st=&pgnum=25).