# Is it permitted to visit a Druze dominant area?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah

I was wondering if its permitted to visit a Druze dominant area, as sometimes when I go to Israel with my family we go there and now since becoming more observant, I'm not so sure of the rules so not sure if its permitted or not.. can someone please help me out? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Do you mean a mosque, or a general region? Note that druze is at least nominally monotheistic

Comment: General region, Its just a druze village that we tend to visit sometimes.

Comment: @Yemimah OK and all my neighbors are Christian. I don't think it matters if you live in a city dominated by people of other faiths besides Judaism. Just know that it'll be very hard to be a practicing Jew, as there won't be a synagogue, eruv, kosher restaurants and markets, etc.

Comment: Thank you Ezra. it is very difficult to be a practicing Jew as I don't live nearby those things..

Answer (score 2):

While it is hard to prove the negative, based on my knowledge there would be no specific prohibition on going to Druze areas. Indeed, most of the world is controlled by people other than Jews, such as Christians, who are considered worshipers of avoda zara, (see e.g. [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26265/8775)), yet many Jews frequent and have frequented Christian areas, and as far as I know, no problems have been raised.

Incidentally, Druze is at least nominally monotheistic. For a discussion of the status of the Druze, see [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/6495), including the view of [R. Uri Cohen](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9F_(%D7%A8%D7%91)) that it is not avoda zara.