# Does Judaism believe that observant Christians follow the 7 mitzvot?

Tags: christianity, noachide-laws, noahidism

My understanding is that Judaism considers the Noahide Laws to be binding on all humans. While Christians believe themselves to be observant of the Noahide Laws, I'm curious whether there are differences of interpretation such that Judaism teaches Christianity to be in unknowing violation of them. It would seem that observant mainstream (noting the distinction between mainstream and mainline) Christians live in accordance with them all, with the only possible exception of not committing idolatry. So my question probably reduces to, does Judaism teach that Christians (some or all) commit idolatry?

This itself is complicated, because some Christians (certain Protestants) believe Catholics and Orthodox commit idolatry to Mary and the Saints, while those who practice defend these practices as not being worship. And all mainstream Christians think that Mormons to be polytheistic idolaters. Meanwhile, Jehovah's Witnesses and other Unitarians (who are outside the mainstream) consider Trinitarianism to be idolatry. Where does Judaism draw the line in terms of idolatry between Unitarians vs Protestants vs Catholic/Orthodox vs Mormons?

And finally, are there any other differences in interpretation of the remaining Noahide Laws?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for this important question. There are many related questions already, that might help you. Check these two out for example: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89/is-christianity-avodah-zara, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/118834/31534

Comment: I believe that this question is off-topic here, because it requires an understanding of the practices of non-Jewish religions.

Comment: The Rambam says to be a noahide, you have to fulfill the laws with that in mind. A Christian who happens to fulfill the laws doesn't count l. You can't incidentally be a Noahide. According to some interpretations, you can't have any religious practices of your own.

Comment: @ClintEastwood just to be pedantic (sorry) but I don't know if the Rambam uses the word Noahide in this context - he's talking about a chassid umot olam, a particularly elevated non-Jew who does the 7 mitzvot because they are Hashem's mitzvot. Then there is a righteous among the nations who does them for rational reasons.